# Partition a set into subsets of size $k$

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, partitions

Given a set $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{lk}\}$ and a positive integer $l$, how can I find all the partitions which includes subsets of size $l$ in Mathematica? For instance, given `{1,2,3,4}` and `l=2`, the output should be:

$$\text{Partition 1: }\{1,2\},\{3,4\}$$ 
$$\text{Partition 2: }\{1,3\},\{2,4\}$$ 
$$\text{Partition 3: }\{1,4\},\{2,3\}$$

In Mathematica notation:

```
{
 {{1,2},{3,4}},
 {{1,3},{2,4}},
 {{1,4},{2,3}}
}
```

Edit: Another example for `l=3`, and `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`:

```
{
 {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, 
 {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 5, 6}}, 
 {{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 6}}, 
 {{1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 5}},
 {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 6}},
 {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}}, 
 {{1, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}},
 {{1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 6}},
 {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 5}},
 {{1, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4}}
}
```

Comment: @murray: I think it would be clear if you read the example. The size of the set is $kl$, so it can be simply partitioned into $k$ subsets of size $l$. I am looking for all such partitions.

Comment: @Mohsen, yes, I know you use $k$ and $l$ but unfortunately in your example, $k$ = $l$ = 2. Which is why it's hardly the best example one might start from.

Comment: @murray: I just added a new example with $k=2$ and $l=3$.

Comment: Somewhat related (note to self): [(5036)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5036)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try with

```
partitions[list_, l_] := Join @@
  Table[
    {x, ##} & @@@ partitions[list ~Complement~ x, l],
    {x, Subsets[list, {l}, Binomial[Length[list] - 1, l - 1]]}
  ]

partitions[list_, l_] /; Length[list] === l := {{list}}
```

The list must have a length multiple of l

Comment: Could someone explain this awesome but mysterious function?

Comment: @AndyS Start here, where Rojo explained his algorithm to me: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3837894#3837894  Later I refactored the code, hopefully for the better.  If the difficulty lies in the syntax rather than the algorithm let me know and I'll explain it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Would you be able to come up with an incremental version of this.  I need the partitions lexicographically sorted one at a time, so that I can generate one, process, and move on to the next one.  This way I can check many more than fit in my laptop.  I could even stop and restart.  This is terrific code, so I wonder if something like it can be done for the problem I am asking about ... or should I start a post? I am not sure I would know how to write it code like this for what I want.  I could work with in lists of say 20 elements as opposed to 16 ... very significant in my world.

Comment: @EGME I suggest you start a new Quesiton.  This is Rojo's code, and unfortunately it appears he doesn't post here any more.  Nevertheless I'll try my hand at it tomorrow, but you'll probably have an answer by then.  You may find it best to work in blocks of partitions rather than one partition at a time, as the latter is typically quite slow in top-level *Mathematica* code.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I posted https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/210033/53849

Answer (score 16):

I believe this is correct.  It is based on [`BellList` from Robert M. Dickau](https://web.archive.org/web/20180110063111/http://mathforum.org/advanced/robertd/bell.html).

```
Module[{n = 4, q = 2, r, BellList},
 r = n/q;
 BellList[1] = {{{1}}};
 BellList[n_Integer?Positive] :=
  Join @@ (ReplaceList[#,
         {{b___, {S : Repeated[_, {1, q - 1}]}, a___} :> {b, {S, n}, a},
         {S : Repeated[_, {1, r - 1}]} :> {S, {n}}}
        ] & /@ BellList[n - 1]);
 BellList[n]
]
```

You'll have to make sure `n` is divisible by `q` or adapt it to behave as you want.  Also, this uses natural numbers for the set, but these in turn can be used as indices to extract elements from the working set.

Comment: +1 for throwing in the formal name of the problem. I had a hard time googling it.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Subsets`:

```
Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2}]
```

Gives:

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}
```

---

**Edit** How about:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ (Sort /@ Partition[#, 2] & /@ Permutations[a, {4}])]
```

which outputs

```
 {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}}
```

Comment: Actually, I am looking for partitions, not permutations. So, $\{1,2\},\{3,4\}$ is one partition and $\{1,3\},\{2,4\}$ is another one. I just edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: How's this version?

Answer (score 3):

Really lazy search through all partitioned permutations:

```
set = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Union[Sort /@ (Sort /@ Partition[#, 2] & /@ 
     Permutations[set, {4}])]
```

> ```
> {
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}},
> {{1, 3}, {2, 4}},
> {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}
> }
> ```

And a more economic one:

```
set = {1, 2, 3, 4};
subsets = Subsets[set, {2}];
Table[{i, Cases[subsets, _?(Union[#, i] === set &)]}, {i, 
   Take[subsets, Length@subsets/2]}]
```

> ```
> {
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}},
> {{1, 3}, {2, 4}},
> {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}
> }
> ```

This generates all the subsets of size 2 (6 of them), and scans through them one-by-one to find their complement in the same list. Since it can be assumed that the output of `Subsets` is regular, the above can be simplified to simply split the `subsets` list to two, and merging the first half with the reversed second half.:

```
n = Length@subsets;
MapThread[List, {Take[subsets, n/2], Take[Reverse@subsets, n/2]}]
```

Comment: Thanks István, actually I am looking for a solution for a general $l$, not only $l=2$. So, your last solution doesn't help, but the other ones looks great. I tested them for $l=3$ and $k=3$ (i.e., 9 numbers) and they work perfect, but for 12 numbers they don't. Is there any way to solve the issue or there are too many partitions with $l=3$ and $k=4$, ummm?

Comment: Yes, I have realized that, so I am now working on a general solution. For the worst, one can do a partial tree-traversal by fixing the first digit and changing the next one, fixing it and changing the next one, etc... I'm pretty sure that before I could solve this, others will post some beautiful answers.

Answer (score 2):

You might start with the `Combinatorica` add-on function `SetPartitions` and then select those partitions satisfying the condition about the size of their members. But this may be too "extravagant" an approach when the original set size becomes a bit big.

Answer (score 1):

```
subsetsPartition[list_, n_] := 
 Select[Subsets[Subsets[list, {n}], {Length[list]/n}], DuplicateFreeQ@*Catenate]

subsetsPartition[Range[4], 2]
subsetsPartition[Range[6], 2]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}}
>
> {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3,6}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4,     6}},
>   {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{1,     4}, {2,
>   5}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {4,
>       6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}}, {{1,     6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}}}