# Can Tuples help simplify this?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and wish to form

```
 {{{1,2},{3,4}}, 
 {{1,3},{2,4}}, 
 {{1,4},{2,3}}}
```

I ended up doing it manually like this:

```
a={1,2,3,4}
{{{a[[1]],a[[2]]}, {a[[3]],a[[4]]}},
{{a[[1]],a[[3]]}, {a[[2]],a[[4]]}},
{{a[[1]],a[[4]]}, {a[[2]],a[[3]]}}}
```

Is there a way to do this more simply?  Of course this is a simplified question from the actual problem which is more complicated.  An answer to this can be generalized to my actual problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you say which rule results in the partitioning ? If there is one you would apply it to `Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2}]`.

Comment: Does [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3044/89) question/answer about [Bell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_numbers) do what you expect? If yes, then this is a dupe.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: Show your actual problem. Your remark about generalizing is not likely to be correct, because different methods for this will have different limitations.

Answer (score 2):

When I understood right what you try to achieve, then yes, there are some ways. Whether it still works in your real life example is another thing. Let me give two examples:

### 1. Method

```
Select[Nest[Subsets[#, {2}] &, {1, 2, 3, 4}, 2], 
 Intersection @@ # === {} &]
```

Here, we create first all possible subsets of length 2 of `{1,2,3,4}`. Then we do this step again which leaves us with elements of the form `{{1, 4}, {2, 3}}` but, there are cases when a number which is in the first part appears in the last part too. Therefore, we select only those elements, where the `Intersection` of the first and the last part is the empty set.

### 2. Method

```
Union[Map[Sort, Partition[#, 2] & /@ Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4}], -2]]
```

Here, we create **all permutations** which will probably not work in your real case. Than we partition those permutations into the correct form. This contains the elements `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}` **and** `{{1, 2}, {4, 3}}`. Therefore, we sort all first and last parts and delete the duplicates with `Union`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
Cases[KSetPartitions[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 2], ConstantArray[{_, _}, 2]]
```

=>

> {
>
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}},
>
> {{1, 4}, {2, 3}},
>
> {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}
>
> }

Extending the method to a list with 6 elements:

```
Cases[KSetPartitions[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 3], ConstantArray[{_, _}, 3]]
```

=>

> {
>
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}},
> {{1, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}},
>
> {{1, 2}, {3,5}, {4, 6}},
> {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}},
>
> {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 6}},
> {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}},
>
> {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {4, 5}},
> {{1, 5}, {2,3}, {4, 6}},
>
> {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 6}},
> {{1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}},
>
> {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}},
> {{1, 6}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}},
>
> {{1,4}, {2, 6}, {3, 5}},
> {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}},
>
> {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}
>
> }

**Edit**

See [Rojo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/109/rojo)'s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3050/106) to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3044/106) for a much better method.