# Combinations which do not have elements in common

Tags: combinatorics, probability-or-statistics

I can choose 2 letters from the four letters $\{A,B,C,D\}$ in 6 combinations using the combination formula

$$\frac{n!}{ r! (n-r)!}$$

```
{A, B}, {A, C}, {A, D}, {B, C}, {B, D}, {C, D}
```

Consider now the collection of all *subsets* of a set of $n$ elements and restrict to those having exactly cardinality $k$, such as $k=2$ above.  How can I find all combinations of groups of 2 or 3 or ... or $n$ (should be dynamic) of these which do not have letters in common?  So, for example, I am expecting the result for combinations of two groups of $k=2$ elements to be the three collections below:

```
{{A, B}, {C, D}},

{{A, C}, {B, D}},

{{A, D}, {B, C}}
```

This is just a small example but I would like the algorithm to work for a large number of sets (I have more than 35000 sets).

Comment: The number of letters change or you will just use 4?

Comment: Aren't they the permutations, properly splitted?

Comment: @belisarius I don't think so. For example, splitting ABCD into groups of two gives the same partition as splitting BACD, ABDC, BACD, CDAB, etc.

Comment: how long are the individual arrays?

Comment: @whuber Oh, I see now. Thanks.

Comment: user, this may be a duplicate of your question, though phrased differently: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3044/121 -- please review that, and if it is not, make clear in this question why not.

Comment: Yes, it is same, i couldn't find it. But I am not from pure mathematics, I am a programmer so want the programming algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: user, I think you will find a couple of nice "programming algorithms" under that question.  Closed as duplicate, in accordance with your statement above.

Comment: @whuber I read the question exactly the same way as you did, and Mr.W and I had a discussion in chat (when this was asked) on whether the OP really meant what you and I interpreted it as, or as what Mr.W interpreted it as (the dupe). We decided to ask the OP and per their clarification (see the 3 comments above mine) it indeed is a dupe of the other one. However, I don't believe in blindly closing it as a dupe and letting your good answer go to waste. ([1/2] continued...)

Comment: [2/2] Since the OP's problem has been solved already, if you could please help rephrase this post to ask for all collections of $m$ disjoint $k$ subsets with a simple example (since we don't have a question on that), and also link to the simpler problem for those looking for that, then I'll definitely reopen this one. Just ping me

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks. I wasn't aware of the chat, but I did read the comments here. IMHO, the OP was mistaken in thinking the two questions are the same!  I'll take a stab at your proposed solution.

Comment: @whuber It was [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=9050075#9050075) and a few messages from there on till the break.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is desired to find all collections $P = \{A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_m\}$ of $m$ disjoint $k$-subsets of a finite set $X$.  Such collections consist of two types: those which include a specified element of $X$ (say $a$) and those that do not.  If $a \in A_j$ for some $j$ then we might as well reindex the elements of $P$ so that $j=1$.  All possibilities for $A_1$ are found by adjoining all possible $k-1$-element subsets of $X - {a}$ to $a$, whereas all possibilities for the $A_2, \ldots, A_m$ are found recursively for $X - A_1$ with $m=1$.  Otherwise, $a$ is not in any $A_j$ and we are left to find similar collections for $X - {a}$.

This gives the following recursive solution.  It's not fast but it's not slow, either--see the timing example below.

Please note that the number of solutions grows very, very quickly with $k$ and $m$.  Their number is computed with `combinationsCount`, which uses `Multinomial` to obtain

$$\frac{n!}{k!^m (n - m k)! m!}.$$

The numerator is the size of the permutation group on $X$ while the denominator is the size of the stabilizer of any collection $P$: it consists of all permutations that (a) separately permute the elements of the $A_j$, (b) permute the remaining elements in $X - \cup_j A_j$, and (c) then permute the $A_j$ among themselves.

```
combinations[x_List, k_Integer, 0] := {{}};
combinations[x_List, k_Integer, m_Integer] := {};
combinations[x_List, k_Integer, m_Integer] /; 
   k m <= Length[x] && k >= 1 && m >= 1 := Block[{y, with, without},
   y = Prepend[#, First@x] & /@ Subsets[Rest@x, {k - 1}];
   with = Flatten[Table[Prepend[#, z] & /@ combinations[Complement[x, z], k, m - 1], {z, y}], 1];
   without = combinations[Rest@x, k, m];
   with~Join~without
   ];
combinationsCount[n_, k_, m_] := Multinomial @@ Append[ConstantArray[k, m], n  - k m] / m!
```

#### Examples

```
combinationsCount[6, 3, 2]
```

> $10$

```
MatrixForm /@ combinations[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, 3, 2]
```

> $\begin{array}{lllll}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a & b & c \\
>  d & e & f
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a & b & d \\
>  c & e & f
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a & b & e \\
>  c & d & f
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a & b & f \\
>  c & d & e
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a & c & d \\
>  b & e & f
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a & c & e \\
>  b & d & f
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a & c & f \\
>  b & d & e
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a & d & e \\
>  b & c & f
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a & d & f \\
>  b & c & e
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a & e & f \\
>  b & c & d
> \end{array}
> \right)
> \end{array}$

```
combinationsCount[13, 3, 4]
```

> $200200$

```
AbsoluteTiming[Length@combinations[Range@13, 3, 4]]
```

> $\{5.9153384,200200\}$