# Enumerate the 1-factors (perfect matchings) of $K_n$

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, performance-tuning, combinatorics

### Introduction

I would like to enumerate the [1-factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-factor), or (near-)perfect matchings, of the complete graph *K<sub>n</sub>*. The adjacency list representation for *K<sub>n</sub>* is basically { (*x*, *y*) | 1 ≤ *x* < *y* ≤ *n* }.

For example, in the case of *K<sub>3</sub>* = `{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}`, the near-perfect matchings would be
`{{{1, 2}},  {{1, 3}},  {{2, 3}}}`. For *K<sub>4</sub>* = `{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}`, the perfect matchings would be 
`{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}},  {{1, 3}, {2, 4}},  {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}}`.

Here's a nifty little illustration of this inspired by [an example](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IndependentEdgeSetQ.html#364603081) from the documentation:

[image: Nifty]

The number of 1-factors of *K<sub>n</sub>* is given by the odd double factorial: *n*!! if *n* is odd, and (*n* – 1)!! if *n* is even. See how this function grows (as the even double factorial) compared to *n*! below:

```
n        1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10
n!!      1       1       3       3      15      15     105     105     945     945
n!       1       2       6      24     120     720    5040   40320  362880 3628800

n!/n!!   1       2       2       8       8      48      48     384     384    3840
```

(For the sake of brevity, I am ignoring parity when using the *n*!! notation in the row headers.)

### Attempt

My current solution generates the *n*! permutations, partitions each into pairs, and filters them.

```
p[n_] := Partition[#, 2] & /@ Permutations[Range[n]];
one[p_] := Select[p, OrderedQ @ # && And @@ OrderedQ /@ # &];
two[p_] := Select[p, # === Intersection@(Intersection /@ #) &];
```

Solution `one` filters the permutations by requiring each element and each of its contents be sorted.
Solution `two` does the same thing by exploiting the fact that order is ignored in sets.

The first solution can be a magnitude faster than the second solution:

```
With[{n = 9}, TableForm[Table[
   With[{ptemp = p[i]},
    tone = one@ptemp // Timing // First;
    ttwo = two@ptemp // Timing // First;
    {tone, ttwo, ttwo/tone}]
   , {i, n}], 
  TableHeadings -> {Range[n], {"one", "two", "one faster by"}}]]
```

```
    one         two         one faster by
1   0.000017    0.000011    0.6
2   0.000013    0.000019    1.
3   0.000025    0.000037    1.5
4   0.000066    0.000186    2.8
5   0.000520    0.001044    2.01
6   0.001274    0.007714    6.05
7   0.010958    0.047812    4.363
8   0.065019    0.446901    6.873
9   0.572954    3.941633    6.8795
```

### Question

How can achieve this without doing *n*!! times as much work generating all the permutations?

Comment: I added an answer; please tell me if my understanding is correct.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom: Yes, you warned me about that in chat a little while ago. I did change `Permutations[n]` to `Permutations[Range[n]]`, which I believe does not require `Combinatorica\``.

Comment: @hftf wups, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### New answer

I think I had an epiphany.  If correct this question can be recast as [Partition a set into subsets of size $k$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3044/121).
Borrowing ideas from Rojo's excellent answer I wrote:

```
match[x : {_, _}] := {{x}}
match[{a_, b__}] :=
  Join @@ Table[{{a, x}, ##} & @@@ match[{b} ~DeleteCases~ x], {x, {b}}]

match[n_?EvenQ] := match @ Range[n]
match[n_?OddQ]  := DeleteCases[match @ Range[n + 1], {___, n + 1, ___}, {2}]
```

Now:

```
match[13] // Length // Timing
match[14] // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {1.154, 135135}
>
> {0.936, 135135}
> ```

---

(See edit history for my old answer.)

Comment: Hi @Jacob :-) -- okay, I guess I didn't understand after all.

Comment: Hm, I also kept misinterpreting the question for a long while (in chat) (missing the symmetry). Oh well :)

Comment: Hi @Mr.Wizard: Your solution returns `{}` for _n_ < 4, and for _n_ ≥ 4 only matches up the first two pairs of elements (vertices) instead of all `floor(n/2)` pairs. (Of course, for n = 4 or 5, there are two pairs in each 1-factor, so that part is right.)

Comment: I see how your "smarter brute force" works. Instead of considering $n!$ permutations, you considered only ${n\choose2}\choose{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$ subsets of subsets. Too bad it still takes the same 3 seconds for $f(10)$, though!

Comment: @hftf Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Jacob I think you might like my answer now too.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you for the notification, I am excited now :). I hope I can take a closer at it later.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard As with Michael Hale's answer, I would really appreciate an accompanying explanation :) Neither this nor the [linked answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3050/13017) really talks about the wizardry going on in the code.

Comment: @hftf My latest edit strips down the code as much as possible.  I suggest you take another look at it; you *might* find it approachable.  (Parts are still tricky but there's not nearly as much of it, e.g. I could do without Rojo's clever use of `Binomial` as we are only building pairs here.)  If not, I'll give a full explanation tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

We iteratively build up a list of matchings from K2 to Kn. Consider K6. We know that each matching has to contain exactly one of edge 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5, or 1-6, otherwise vertex 1 is excluded or it's covered more than once. So the matchings of K6 can be split into 5 independent sets, each containing matchings including one of the edges touching vertex 1. Each of the matchings in those sets contains the edge incident to vertex 1 plus the matchings of a K4 subgraph. For example, the first set contains all of the K4 matchings for the subraph with vertices 3, 4, 5, and 6 with edge 1-2 added to each of those matchings. So we just use the matchings for Kn to construct the matchings for K(n+2).

For odd n, we just consider n+1 and delete the edges that contain the extra vertex. The Outer command generates all of the matchings for the K(n-2) subgraphs of Kn using the matchings just computed for K(n-2). The MapIndexed and Prepend then add edge 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, etc to the matchings for the subgraphs.

```
perfectMatchingsOfComplete[n_?EvenQ] := 
 Nest[Flatten[
      MapIndexed[Prepend[#, {1, First@#2 + 1}] &, 
       Outer[#[[#2]] &, Reverse@Subsets[Range[2, #2], {#2 - 2}], #, 1,
         2], {2}], 1] &[#, 
    2 Length@First@# + 2] &, {{{1, 2}}}, (n - 2)/2]

perfectMatchingsOfComplete[n_?OddQ] := 
 Select[#, ! MemberQ[#, n + 1] &] & /@ 
  perfectMatchingsOfComplete[n + 1]
```

Result lengths:

```
Length@perfectMatchingsOfComplete@# & /@ Range@14    
{1, 1, 3, 3, 15, 15, 105, 105, 945, 945, 10395, 10395, \
135135, 135135}
```

~20 seconds for n=16:

```
perfectMatchingsOfComplete@16 // Timing // First
19.734
```

Comment: Would you be kind enough to explain how this works? The functions are so deeply nested I'm having a hard time trying to pick out each layer and understand it.

Comment: After a rewrite, it's clearer and 2x faster, so I'll add the explanation to the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this now also works for odd `n`.

```
three[n_] :=
 Block[
  {m = Quotient[n, 2], firstsSeconds, firstsPermuted, dupePairs, 
   sortPairs, range, strange}
  ,
  range = Range[n];
  strange = If[EvenQ[n], range, Range[0, m]];
  firstsSeconds = {If[EvenQ@n, #, #~Append~0] &@#, 
      Complement[range, #]} & /@ Subsets[range, {m}]; ;
  firstsPermuted =
   Function[{firsts, seconds}, {#, seconds} & /@ 
      Permutations[firsts]] @@@ firstsSeconds; ;
  dupePairs = Transpose /@ Flatten[firstsPermuted, 1]; ;
  sortPairs = Map[Sort, #, {1, 2}] &;
  Sort[
   If[OddQ[n], #[[All, 2 ;;]], #] &@
    DeleteDuplicates[sortPairs@dupePairs]
   ]
  ]
```

We have

```
n = 10;
(a = three[n]) //Timing//First
(b = one[p[n]])//Timing//First
a === b
```

> 7.042475
>   0.108956
>   True

and

```
three[5] == one[p[5]]
```

> True

There are still issues with the code though. First and foremost it is O((n/2)!), which should not be necessary.

Comment: Also in this answer it is silly to permute the `firsts` rather than the `seconds`, because that will probably require more sorting afterwards.

Comment: This appears to be really fast, but as you say it only works for even numbers.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard maybe I should just fix that and not be too perfectionistic. There is another Q&A on this site where I got so perfectionistic I ended up never even answering :P

Comment: @Mr.Wizard (I think) I made it work for odd `n` by paring one "vertex"/number with 0, and then removing the 0's.