# Hafnian of a matrix

Tags: matrix, computational-geometry, algebra

Is there a Mathematica built-in function for the calculation of the [Hafnian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafnian) of a matrix? I am interested in the function as it appears naturally in the calculation of moments of a multivariate Gaussian distribution.

Comment: I guess an enterprising soul might be interested in implementing [this](https://doi.org/10.1145/3325111) in *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`match`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44170/1997) function by Mr.Wizard.

```
match[x : {_, _}] := {{x}}
match[{a_, b__}] := 
 Join @@ Table[{{a, x}, ##} & @@@ match[{b}~DeleteCases~x], {x, {b}}]

match[n_?EvenQ] := match@Range[n]
match[n_?OddQ] := 
 DeleteCases[match@Range[n + 1], {___, n + 1, ___}, {2}]
```

Code for Hafnian:

```
haf[m_?MatrixQ] := 
 With[{d = Dimensions[m]}, 
  If[And[Divide @@ d == 1, And @@ EvenQ[d]], 
   Module[{mtc = match[Length[m]]},
    Total[Times @@@ (Extract[m, #] & /@ mtc)]
    ], {}]]
```

Testing:

```
haf[Array[a, {6, 6}]]
```

a[1, 6] a[2, 5] a[3, 4] + a[1, 5] a[2, 6] a[3, 4] +
a[1, 6] a[2, 4] a[3, 5] + a[1, 4] a[2, 6] a[3, 5] +
a[1, 5] a[2, 4] a[3, 6] + a[1, 4] a[2, 5] a[3, 6] +
a[1, 6] a[2, 3] a[4, 5] + a[1, 3] a[2, 6] a[4, 5] +
a[1, 2] a[3, 6] a[4, 5] + a[1, 5] a[2, 3] a[4, 6] +
a[1, 3] a[2, 5] a[4, 6] + a[1, 2] a[3, 5] a[4, 6] +
a[1, 4] a[2, 3] a[5, 6] + a[1, 3] a[2, 4] a[5, 6] +
a[1, 2] a[3, 4] a[5, 6]

Using test cases from @138 Aspen

```
mat1 = {{-1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1}, {1, 
    1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 
    0}, {0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    1}, {1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1}};
mat2={{-1, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1}, {1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 
   1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 
   0, -1, 0, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 
   1}, {0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1}, {-1, 1, 1, 0, 
   1, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1}, {0, -1, -1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 
   0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 
   1}, {-1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 
   0, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 
   0, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
   1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1, 
   1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1}};
 
haf[mat1]
haf[mat2]
```

yields  4 and 83 respectively.

I look forward to learning from other approaches.

As @JM alludes it soons becomes intractable (number perfect matches $\frac{(2n)!}{n! 2^n}$ , as can be be seen by partitioning 2n into pairs and accounting for n pairs and 2 ways to order each pair).

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica

Use the recursive formula.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVNNb5tAEL3zK1Y@JXiQFx/jbKvKVdpIjZo6vm1ourE3NggWhLHUyOK3u/sBZhdQD62EZXZn5s17b4aMVXuesSresPMy5aykky9p/srSX/4kWnhXvveVvYmYCSqTyvj3y8cH/f8juiEP@faYcnoSkL0/HTMoeJkdK4mVi4M@QAJFmW9rePZ0BsELT5BvXOyqfYMXzeYLzy4kj9aBrpjYcYpB@PMghDCSlO7yksYkhPi2RbLLI4inU92c2NeUxqpWsSGhwUgkRnJLBCSqQAZ8YihRDUjp3E8C2XEawuWsTlHkSSStZ0pUXXuaXd2xTZWXMUupiPz5T3EtQ15r4KfNhqe8ZBXf/tVLx8Vn7c3BCL14ajJeUw57g13Df9tq9Rn19QIn25JlnhWxonvSlF7uRcV3vISwhpMhAC8rzlKYywtxiddqE1qlZhaQ1PAv03j2unk0g43A0NKE16zc8Sr4MFlOYHUUVZzx74VWIu@eCs63ar0b@8g6r@TQHlnJ0pSna6WRdnLpYJOgESkiOMVSkyHV2FdHHfL4TvjXZxkfbAG6IchDqAtFiKBuMdAeUAJokxfvNSAhY@7IF7IWofs3KkMEzQGteHUs2w@X0hDQPNJuqby9rMfmVfuPdEmCbgmSrdQUFJRVK81WuBjQMpd@iiOnLZbmJAE@ywWveFME6HSS@4BOSV338tYlE4ciP3CqLsZB1GkMYo@mBLm0fOWYQWrFmQnI/ZTrjcyj3rB@9EHBhu0RX8KBHdRYTWnYxpo0lRKEHZ6TpQuxSsFdLHBIGAR8aWqzM30bEoHDr8lsuwdugnlryusIzWbosYxF5ZrR14wd7rbAEVWOmZ27PVGO6y5P48244QMag@q@QXhYMJhIf2Q9o2xBvVGFlqSg50/3axX1YAbzHTMdt08nqTfT/nI4RHFjXOj6Ggy8dAyyjBjoNl8ZBleQ3QvDIIwHFJ0J4eFI8QjBIOyvtf0BDrywadvLfj7/AQ)

```
haf[matrix_?MatrixQ] := 
  haf[matrix] = Module[{n, h, j, copy}, n = Length[matrix];
    If[n == 2, Return[matrix[[1, 2]]]];
    h = 0;
    For[j = 2, j <= n, j++, If[matrix[[1, j]] == 0, Continue[]];
     copy = Delete[matrix, {{1}, {j}}];
     copy = Transpose[copy];
     copy = Delete[copy, {{1}, {j}}];
     h += matrix[[1, j]]*haf[copy];];
    h];
```