# How to construct the RHS of Wick's theorem

Tags: function-construction, functional-style, code-review, code-request

I've been trying this for a few days now, but I just can't seem to find an efficient (speed-wise) functional way to code the following task.

**Context:**

I would like to construct an expressions that is the result of sorting a product of non-commuting objects (they can be expressions, but we'll use only `Symbol`s for clarity):

```
input = str[j,i,h,g,f,e,d,c,b,a]
```

If these objects were commuting, then `Sort` will do the job.  But I would like to write a (non-commutative sort) `NCSort` that will also include the appropriate commutators `comm[x,y]` for every required pairwise interchange.  Here is the code that recursively performs this task:

```
NCSort[expr_str] := ReplaceRepeated[expr, 
   str[left___, a_, b_, right___] /; ! OrderedQ[{a, b}] :> 
   str[left, b, a, right] + comm[a, b] str[left, right]]
```

It takes 1 sec on my computer to give the result for `NCSort[str[j,i,h,g,f,e,d,c,b,a]]`.  Furthermore, I would like the answer expanded out.  Calling `Expand` on the output takes another 4 seconds.

**Problem:**

To speed things up, it is useful to know that the algebra problem can be turned into an expression-construction problem.  The final result can be written in closed from ([Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem)),

$$
\begin{eqnarray}\text{str}(a,b,c,d,\ldots) &=& \text{sorted}(a,b,c,d,\ldots)\\
&& + \hspace{-5mm}\sum_{\substack{\text{all req'd}\\\text{single comm's}}} \hspace{-5mm} \text{comm}(a,b)\text{sorted}(c,d,\ldots) + \ldots \\
&& + \hspace{-5mm}\sum_{\substack{\text{all req'd}\\\text{double comm's}}} \hspace{-5mm} \text{comm}(a,b)\text{comm}(c,d)\text{sorted}(\ldots) + \ldots \\
&&\ldots
\end{eqnarray}$$

I need help in directly constructing the entire expression in the RHS.  *Once again for clarification, this is not an algebra problem.  This is an expression-construction problem*.  The end result should be identical to the output of `NCSort[str[j,i,h,g,f,e,d,c,b,a]]//Expand` given above.

---

**What I have so far**

Instead of using `Sum` I'm thinking it would be faster to write this functionally.  I have pieces that would potentially be useful, but I can't quite put it all together, and that is where I need help.

This will select all possible subsets containing elements of the input string that would be involved in `comm`:

```
elementsInvolvedInCommutator[input_str, n_?EvenQ] := Subsets[List @@ input, {n}]
```

If `n` is 4 or greater, then they need to be partitioned into pairs (inspired by [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/partition-a-set-into-subsets-of-size-k)). *This involves recursion, so the spirit of the solution is lost here.  I need help*:

```
allPairwisePartitions[l : {_, _}] := {{l}}

allPairwisePartitions[list_] := 
 Join @@ Function[x, 
   Apply[{x, ##} &, 
     allPairwisePartitions[
       DeleteCases[list, Alternatives @@ x]], {1}]] /@ 
         Subsets[list, {2}, Length[list] - 1]
```

If I put the above two together, I can get all the pairwise commutators involved in a given sum.  For example, the following gives a list of all potential double commutators (third line in the equation above):

```
Join @@ (allPairwisePartitions /@ elementsInvolvedInCommutator[input, 4])
```

I'm having trouble proceeding from here.  I am unable to remove the commutators that are not needed, *i.e.* those that are already in order, and I need help writing `allPairwisePartitions` non-recursively.

Comment: Do you really want the RHS as written or do you want all the Wick contractions?  I know of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01576v1 and https://github.com/djukanovic/qct.git .  I also have my own (IMHO more elegant) contraction generator.

Comment: @evanb I'd like the result of the `NCSort[input]//Expand` given above which is basically the RHS of Wick's theorem.  Note however, only the contractions required to sort the input appear and not all of them.

Comment: @evan, even if it should turn out to not be what the OP wants, can you maybe post it (if needed, as a self-answered question)? That looks interesting in itself.

Comment: @evanb Yes, please post whatever it is; any hints would be helpful.

Comment: There is a subsection [in here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262223580_Symbolic_FAQ) that has code for working with commutators and canonicalizing the order of factors.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I'm not seeing exactly which subsection I should be looking at.  My question is closer to constructing an expression rather than doing algebra.

Comment: I think it was the coding of `ncTimes` that looked appropriate for canonicalizing in presence of commutators.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't an exact answer as for how to construct `NCSort`.  However, it is the core of my approach for generating Wick contractions.

I ripped out all the bells and whistles.

It helps to have some background:  I do lattice QCD, and so I mostly think about quark contractions.  So, if you see "quark" you can parse that as "fermion".  My code is designed to Wick contract a big NonCommutativeMultiply of quark operators, which are denoted `quarkFlavor[spaceTimePoint][spinIndex,colorIndex]` where `quarkFlavor`, `spaceTimePoint`, `spinIndex` and `colorIndex` can be whatever you want, as long as they make sense physically.  In the lengthy version of this code, spin indices talk to gamma matrices, color indices talk to epsilon tensors, etc.  But I've ripped out all of that in this answer because it's too much.

What really needs to be known is how to handle `bar` (ie. $\bar{q}$):

```
Clear[bar];
(* bar^2 is the identity: *)
bar[bar[f_]] := f;
(* Complex conjugate numbers: *)
bar[c_] := Conjugate[c] /; NumericQ[c];
(* Distribute over addition: *)
bar[Plus[a_, addends__]] := bar[a] + bar[Plus[addends]];
(* Distribute over multiplication: *)
bar[Times[f_, factors__]] := bar[Times[factors]] bar[f];
(* Be careful to reverse order of noncommutative multiplication: *)
bar[Times[s_., NonCommutativeMultiply[NCM___]]] := bar[s] NonCommutativeMultiply @@ bar /@ Reverse@{NCM}
(* quark flavor just bars the flavor: *)
bar[f_[x_][s_, c_]] := bar[f][x][s, c] /; Not[f === γ]
```

Then, I have some little helper functions:

```
appearanceOf[lst_][arg_] := FromDigits[
     1 - Boole@Through[(FreeQ /@ (Reverse@lst))@#], 2] &@arg;

Clear[flavor, spacetime, spin, color];
flavor[S[f_][x_][s_, c_]] := f;
flavor[f_[x_][s_, c_]] := f;
spacetime[f_[x_][s_, c_]] := x;
spin[f_[x_][s_, c_]] := s;
color[f_[x_][s_, c_]] := c;
```

And some utilities that help make writing big contractions easier:

```
(* 
 * Things for which ScalarQ are true are just numbers, in the sense that they are not anticommuting
 * once you've written out all the indices.
 *)
Clear[ScalarQ];
ScalarQ[c_?NumericQ] :=True; (* anything that Mma thinks is a number *)
ScalarQ[ϵ[idx___]] := True; (* epsilon tensors *)
ScalarQ[δ[idx___]] := True; (* kronecker deltas *)
ScalarQ[γ[_][__]] := True; (* gamma matrices *)
ScalarQ[S[__][__]] := True; (* propagators *)
ScalarQ[q[__][__]] := False;(* quarks *)

Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
Clear[NonCommutativeMultiply];
(* Flatness causes some pattern matching infinite loops.  Get rid of it: *)
ClearAttributes[NonCommutativeMultiply, Flat];
(* Pauli exclusion principle: *)
NonCommutativeMultiply[h___, a_, m___, a_, t___] := 0 
(* Distribute over addition: *)
NonCommutativeMultiply[h___, Plus[a_, addends__], t___] := NonCommutativeMultiply[h, a, t] + NonCommutativeMultiply[h, Plus[addends], t];
(* Scalars commute freely: *)
NonCommutativeMultiply[h___, Times[c_?ScalarQ, factors__], t___] :=  c NonCommutativeMultiply[h, Times[factors], t];
(* Scalars can be pulled out: *)
NonCommutativeMultiply[h___, c_?ScalarQ, t___] := c NonCommutativeMultiply[h, t]
(* One-way flatness is OK: *)
NonCommutativeMultiply[h___, NonCommutativeMultiply[NCM___], t___] := NonCommutativeMultiply[h, NCM, t];
(* The empty product is 1: *)
NonCommutativeMultiply[] := 1
```

And finally, the main show:

```
Clear[wickContract];
wickContract[Plus[a_, addends__]] := ExpandAll[wickContract[a] + wickContract[Plus[addends]]];
wickContract[Times[c_?ScalarQ, factors__]] := ExpandAll[c wickContract[Times[factors]]];
wickContract[] := 1;

wickContract[NonCommutativeMultiply[NCM___]] :=With[{
  quarks = {NCM},
  allFlavors = Union[flavor /@ {NCM} /. bar[f_] :> f]
  },
  (* Mandate that quarks appear in Overscript[q, _]q pairs: *)
  If[Not[SameQ[
    (allFlavors /. CountsBy[Select[FreeQ[bar]][quarks], flavor]),
    (bar /@ allFlavors) /. CountsBy[Select[Not@*FreeQ[bar]][quarks], flavor]]], 
    Print["Flavor mismatch."]; Return[0]];
  With[{
    sorted = Join[
      SortBy[Select[FreeQ[bar]][quarks], appearanceOf[allFlavors]],
      Reverse@SortBy[Select[Not@*FreeQ[bar]][quarks], appearanceOf[allFlavors]]
      ]},
  With[{
    qs = SplitBy[Select[FreeQ[bar]][sorted], flavor],
    qbars = Reverse@SplitBy[Select[Not@*FreeQ[bar]][sorted], flavor]
    },
    (Signature[List @@ quarks] Signature[sorted]) Times @@ MapThread[
      Function[{fs, fbars}, 
    Total[Map[
      Function[c, Signature[c] Times @@ MapThread[
        Function[{q, qbar}, S[flavor[q]][ spacetime[q] ← spacetime[qbar]][
          spin /@ {q, qbar}, color /@ {q, qbar}]], {fs, fbars[[c]]}]], 
      Permutations[Range[Length[fs]]]]]], {qs, qbars}]
]]]
```

Then, a proton at `xf` from a proton at `xi` looks like

```
wickContract[(
  u[xf][μ, a[xf]] ** u[xf][ρ[xf], b[xf]] ** d[xf][σ[xf], c[xf]])
  ** (bar[d][xi][σ[xi], c[xi]] ** bar[u][xi][ρ[xi], b[xi]] ** bar[u][xi][ν, a[xi]])
  ]
```

yields

```
S[d][xf ← xi][{σ[xf], σ[xi]}, {c[c[xi]}] (
  S[u][xf ← xi][{μ, ρ[xi]}, {a[xf], b[xi]}] 
  S[u][xf ← xi][{ρ[xf], ν}, {b[xf], a[xi]}] 
 -S[u][xf ← xi][{μ, ν}, {a[xf], a[xi]}] 
  S[u][xf ← xi][{ρ[xf], ρ[xi]}, {b[xf], b[xi]}]
  )
```

Where `S[flavor][sink ← source][{mu,nu},{a,b}]` represents a quark propagator of flavor `flavor` from `source` to `sink` with spin indices `{mu,nu}` at the sink and source and color indices `{a,b}` at the sink and source.

I have tested [the full version of] this code on a single proton correlator, a two-proton correlator, a proton-neutron correlator, proton-meson correlators, and a few others with correct results.

The rest of my code makes it easy to put in all the appropriate gamma matrices, epsilon tensors, etc etc etc., but that's definitely beyond the scope of this question.  I would consider writing up a short note and putting the code on github with a manual on the arXiv if there's enough interest.

Comment: `ScalarQ` seems to be undefined

Comment: Ah, you're right.  Still, if you don't try to `wickContract` something that isn't a big `NonCommutativeMultiply` it should work correctly.  `ScalarQ` is basically a predicate I have to filter out epsilon tensors, gamma matrices, (ie. things that aren't fermions / things that are just commuting numbers once all the indices are written out).  I can post what I have when I get to the office.

Comment: OK, updated with ScalarQ and some ** tricks.