# Listing all distinct exhaustive combinations of sublists of a certain length

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, combinatorics

I would like to do the following:

Suppose there is a list `{a, b, c, d}`. I would like to get all distinct exhaustive combinations of its sublists of a certain length, so for this specific list I would like to get

> { {a, b}{c, d} , {a, c}{b, d} , {a, d}{b, c} }.

Now suppose I have multiple such lists, and I would like to do this operation on each of them. How should we do this?

The result does not have to be a list object of sublists; as long as it is clear how elements are paired anything is fine.

Comment: Here's a brute force method:  `DeleteDuplicates[Sort[#] & /@ Permutations[{a, b, c, d}, {2}]]`.

Comment: @JimBaldwin This doesn't seem to do what I need. It gives individual sublists of length 2, but I need combinations of such length-2 sublists that cover all elements in the original list without repetition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that your request for `{}{}` is non-syntactic, I'll assume that you want lists of such sublists:

```
mylist = {a,b,c,d};

DeleteDuplicates[
 Map[Sort, 
  Map[Sort, 
   Partition[#, 2] & /@ (Sort[Permutations[mylist]]), {2}], {2}]]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very close to what I want. Would it be possible to delete duplicate combinations of the same sublists? So for example, keep only one of `{{a, c}, {b, d}}` and `{{b, d}, {a, c}}`.

Comment: Is one of `Map[Sort, ..., {2}]` intended to have level `{1}`? You can take care of both levels in one `Map` call using `Map[Sort, ..., 2]`

Answer (score 5):

I will assume that for a set like $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ you want partitions of the form:
$$(1, 2)(3, 4)(5, 6), (1, 3)(2, 4)(5, 6), ...$$
In this case, the following semi-brute force method will work:

```
f[set_]:=With[{sort=Sort@set},
    DeleteCases[
        Subsets[Subsets[set,{2}], {Length[set]/2}],
        x_ /; Sort@Flatten@x =!= sort
    ]
]
```

For example:

```
f[{a, b, c, d}]
f[Range[6]]
```

> {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{a, c}, {b, d}}, {{a, d}, {b, c}}}
>
> {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 
>      5}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 
>      6}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 
>      4}, {2, 6}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 
>      6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 
>      4}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}}}

Comment: Since I know you value performance I think you'll find [(3050)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3050/121) interesting.

Answer (score 2):

This gives the orderings you need:

```
next[cur_, rem_, n_] := If[Length[cur] =!= n, next[Join[cur, rem[[#]]], rem[[# + 1 ;;]], n] & /@
                     Position[DisjointQ[cur, #] & /@ rem, True, {1}][[All, 1]], Sow[cur]; 0]

make[n_] := Catenate[With[{subs = Subsets[Range[n], {2}]},
              Table[Reap[next[subs[[i - 1]], subs[[i ;;]], n]][[2, 1]], {i, 2, n}]]]

make[6]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 2,
>      4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6}, {1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5}, {1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 
>     6}, {1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 5}, {1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 
>     5, 2, 4, 3, 6}, {1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4}, {1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 6, 2, 4,
>      3, 5}, {1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4}}

Comment: This doesn't seem to exactly do what I need: it gives individual sublists of length 2, like {a, b}, {c, d}, etc., but I need "products of sublists" like {a, b}{c, d}, {a, c}{b, d}, etc.

Comment: @Rethliopuks Are you lists like `{a, b, c, d}` always with length 4?

Comment: Their lengths are always an even number. Currently I am only dealing with length 4 and length 6, though I might be doing length 8 some point in the future.

Comment: In fact the sublists only need to be length 2 -- in other word I need to regroup the original list into pairs and find all possibilities of such grouping.

Comment: The {}{} construct is non-syntactic in *Mathematica*.  Why would you ever want that?  And what would you want for `{a,b,c,d,e,f}`?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork My apologies for not being familiar with Mathematica's syntax. For that list the result would be a long one (bear with my wrong syntax): 
[[a,b][c,d][e,f]], [[a,b][c,e][d,f]], [[a,b][c,f][d,e]], 
[[a,c][b,d][e,f]], [[a,c][b,e][d,f]], [[a,c][b,f][d,e]], 
[[a,d][b,c][e,f]], [[a,d][b,e][c,f]], [[a,d][b,f][c,e]], 
[[a,e][b,c][d,f]], [[a,e][b,d][c,f]], [[a,e][b,f][c,d]], 
[[a,f][b,c][d,e]], [[a,f][b,d][c,e]], [[a,f][b,e][c,d]].

Comment: @Rethliopuks:  Even your revised syntax makes no sense in *Mathematica*.  What are you *really* trying to do?  *Why* do you want this function?

Comment: I changed the syntax because I knew I was probably going to get it wrong anyway and the exact format of the result wouldn't matter either. I just need all the distinct pairings of the elements of the original list. More specifically I am trying to compute a tri-spectrum, aka a "four-point correlation", which requires me to break down products of an even number of functions into products of the products of pairs of these functions, and I need to sum all the possible products. I thought that in form this was identical to what I was asking, hence the question that seem to have come out of nowhere

Comment: Ah...and I changed the syntax just to make it hopefully a bit more legible.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {a, b, c, d};

Cases[Permutations@list, {x : First@list, b_, c_, d_} /; 
   OrderedQ@{x, b} && OrderedQ@{c, d} :> {{x, b}, {c, d}}]
```

> {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{a, c}, {b, d}}, {{a, d}, {b, c}}}