# $2+2+\dots+2$ cycle conjugation classes of the symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation, group-theory

Command `GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[4]]` gives me all cycles of all conjugation classes. But I'm only interested in the 2+2 class ($2+2$ being one of the integer partitions of $n=4$ corresponding to the cycle of size 3 in this case). I could filter out all three cycles from the result but  for the partition $\underbrace{2+2+\dots+2}_{n/2}$ it is impractical and slow for a bigger $n$ since it lists all $2^n$ cycles -- the size of the class I'm after is 'only' $(n-1)!!$. How to generate them directly and fast (at least for moderate $n\approx20$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `partitions` from Rojo's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3050/45431) to [Partition a set into subsets of size $k$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3044/45431):

```
partitions[list_, l_] := Join @@
  Table[
    {x, ##} & @@@ partitions[list ~Complement~ x, l],
    {x, Subsets[list, {l}, Binomial[Length[list] - 1, l - 1]]}
  ]

partitions[list_, l_] /; Length[list] === l := {{list}}
```

For example:

```
partitions[Range[4], 2]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}}

and

```
partitions[Range[10], 2] //Length
9!!
```

> 945
>
> 945

His function will work reasonable fast up to about $n=16$. If you need to go to $n=20$, you might want to figure out how to speed it up.

**Addendum**

A slight speedup can be obtained by using memoization:

```
partitions2[list_, l_] := partitions2[list, l] = Join @@
  Table[
    {x, ##} & @@@ partitions2[list ~Complement~ x, l],
    {x, Subsets[list, {l}, Binomial[Length[list] - 1, l - 1]]}
  ]

partitions2[list_, l_] /; Length[list] === l := {{list}}
```

A speed comparison:

```
r1 = partitions[Range[16], 2];//AbsoluteTiming
r2 = partitions2[Range[16], 2]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {26.1082, Null}
>
> {4.3307, Null}
>
> True

Still, since 18 produces 34459425 partitions and 20 produces 654729075 partitions, you probably will need to come up with a version that produces only a subset of the total.

Comment: Great, that is what I need, thanks

Comment: That macro is complicated for me to be able to speed it up. Could somebody help?