# Non crossing set partitions

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

A set partition is noncrossing if whenever four elements $a<b<c<d$ are such that $a,c$ are in the same block and $b,d$ are in the same block then $a,b,c,d$ are all in the same block.

Can I get a list of noncrossing set partitions.

With "Combinatorica" I can get ALL the set partitions (say of {1,2,3,4}) with the command SetPartitions[4].

What I want is this list without the element {{1,3},{2,4}} which is not noncrossing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]

ClearAll[nonCrossingSetPartitions]
nonCrossingSetPartitions = 
    DeleteCases[{___, {___, a_, ___, c_, ___}, ___, {___, b_, ___, d_, ___}, ___} /;
       a < b < c < d] @* SetPartitions;

nonCrossingSetPartitions @ 4 // Column
```

[image]

```
nonCrossingSetPartitions @ 5 // Length
```

> 42

Comment: There should be 42 noncrossing partitions of [5].

Comment: thank you @geoffrey. Updated with a fix.

Answer (score 6):

I have a [Mathematica package for generating Catalan objects](https://github.com/PerAlexandersson/Mathematica-packages/blob/master/CatalanObjects.m) on GitHub,
so I have some recursive algorithm which generates what you want.
Moreover, it has a nice graphical representation of these,
and some operations on these, such as rotation.

Just download the package, and
do

```
Needs["CatalanObjects`"]
Last /@ NonCrossingPartitions[4]
```

to get

```
{{{1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{3}, {1, 2, 4}}, {{2}, {1, 3, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 
   3}}, {{2}, {3}, {1, 4}}, {{1}, {2, 3, 4}}, {{1}, {3}, {2, 4}}, {{1,
    2}, {3, 4}}, {{1}, {2}, {3, 4}}, {{4}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{2}, {4}, {1, 
   3}}, {{1}, {4}, {2, 3}}, {{3}, {4}, {1, 2}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}}
```

If you do not want everything in the package,
it should be easy to extract the method.

Comment: Useful package, did you ever implemented [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/partition-a-set-into-subsets-of-size-k)?

Comment: @matrix89 I usually use the subsets function for that.