# List of lists with non-repeating elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following lists:

```
l1 = {{a,b},{a,c},{a,d},{a,e},{a,f}};
l2 = {{b,c},{b,d},{b,e},{b,f}};
l3 = {{c,d},{c,e},{c,f}};
l4 = {{d,e},{d,f}};
l5 = {e,f};
```

I want to create a list of combinations of exactly three of the above sublists, with no repeating elemenst. It should look like:

```
L = {{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}},{{a,b},{c,e},{d,f}},...,{{{a,c},{b,d},{e,f}}...};
```

For example, for four lists $l$ with elements {a,b,c,d}, the final list should look like this:

```
L = {{{a,b},{c,d}},{{a,c},{b,d}},{{a,d},{b,c}}};
```

For five lists $l$, the dimensions should be {15,3,2}, but I want to generalize this for more lists $l$. As the dimension of $L$ grows as $n!!$, I'm trying to write a general code.
Is there an easy way to do this? Thank you!

*EDIT*

As [chyanog](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2090/chyanog) pointed out in the comments, this question has been answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/partition-a-set-into-subsets-of-size-k). The following function posted by [Rojo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/109/rojo) gives a general list $L$ of dimensions $\{n!!,\frac{n}{2},l\}$:

```
  partitions[list_, l_] := Join @@
  Table[
    {x, ##} & @@@ partitions[list ~Complement~ x, l],
    {x, Subsets[list, {l}, Binomial[Length[list] - 1, l - 1]]}
  ]

partitions[list_, l_] /; Length[list] === l := {{list}}
```

, and to get the lists I'm looking for, $l=2$.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3044/2090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wasteful but general code that uses the numbers $1\ldots n$ instead of variables $\{a,b,c,\ldots\}$:

```
f[n_ /; n >= 2 && EvenQ[n]] := 
  Select[Subsets[Subsets[Range[n], {2}], {n/2}], 
         DuplicateFreeQ@*Flatten]

f[2]
(*    {{{1, 2}}}    *)

f[4]
(*    {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}},
       {{1, 3}, {2, 4}},
       {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}}    *)

f[6]
(*    {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}},
       {{1, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 6}},
       {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {4, 5}},
       {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}},
       {{1, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}},
       {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}},
       {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}},
       {{1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}}}                              *)

Table[Length[f[n]], {n, 2, 12, 2}]
(*    {1, 3, 15, 105, 945, 10395}    *)
```

This procedure is easily extended to splitting $n$ numbers (symbols) into non-overlapping bunches of $k$:

```
f[n_Integer?Positive, k_Integer?Positive] /; Divisible[n, k] :=
  Select[Subsets[Subsets[Range[n], {k}], {n/k}],
         DuplicateFreeQ@*Flatten]

f[6, 1]
(*    {{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}}}    *)

f[6, 2]
(*    {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}},
       {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}},
       {{1, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}},
       {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 6}},
       {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 6}},
       {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {4, 5}},
       {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}},
       {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}},
       {{1, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 5}},
       {{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}},
       {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}},
       {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}},
       {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}},
       {{1, 6}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}},
       {{1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}}}    *)

f[6, 3]
(*    {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}},
       {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 5, 6}},
       {{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 6}},
       {{1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 5}},
       {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 6}},
       {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}},
       {{1, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}},
       {{1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 6}},
       {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 5}},
       {{1, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4}}}    *)

f[6, 6]
(*    {{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}}    *)
```