# Permutations with subsets not containing the same elements

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, permutation

I would like to define a function of two integer variables $ \{n, k\} $, with $ k | n $, that would print all the possible permutations of the first $ n$ positive integers, such that the subsets of $ k $ elements never contains $ 2 $ times the same elements of the previous permutations. As an example, this should be the output with $ n = 20, k = 4 $:

$\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, $\{5, 6, 7, 8\}$, $\{9, 10, 11, 12\}$, $\{13, 14, 15, 16\}$, $\{17, 18, 19, 20\}$

$\{1, 5, 9, 13\}$, $\{17, 2, 6, 10\}$, $\{14, 18, 3, 7\}$, $\{11, 15, 19, 4\}$, $\{8, 12, 16, 20\}$

$\{1, 17, 14, 8\}$, $\{5,2,12,15\}$, $\{9, 16, 3, 19\}$, $\{20, 10, 7, 4\}$, $\{11, 18, 6, 13\}$

$ ...$

Comment: Could you give example with much smaller {,} and its **complete** output you expect. Like {3,2} or {4,3}.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Ok, let's say it's $ [4,2] $ (because $ k | n $), so the output would be:

$\{1, 2\}$, $\{3, 4\}$ \
$\{1, 3\}$, $\{2, 4\}$ \
$\{1, 4\}$, $\{2, 3\}$ 

With the slash intended as new line

Comment: Related: [partition-a-set-into-subsets-of-size-k](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/partition-a-set-into-subsets-of-size-k)

Answer (score 1):

We may first create all k subsets of 1..n;

Then we need to select n/k subsets that have no common elements. Toward this aim we define a function that, given a number of subsets, selects a further subset that has no common element. It repeats this recursively until n/k subsets.  We then feed the first subset to our routine, then the second e.t.c until we fed all subsets starting with 1. Finally we join all results.

```
main[n_, k_] := Module[{d = Range[n], p, step},
If[! Divisible[n, k], Print["n not divisible by k."]; Return[]];
  p = Subsets[d, {k}];
  
  step[e1_] := Module[{es = Flatten[e1], new, res,fun},
    fun[e_] := ( 
      new = Select[p, (! IntersectingQ[Flatten[{e}], #]) &];
      Append[e, #] & /@ new);
    
    res = Flatten[fun /@ e1, 1];
    If[Length[res[[1]]] == n/k, res, step[res]]
    ];
  
  Join @@ Reap[
     Do[
      Sow[step[{{p[[1]]}}]];
      p = Rest[p];
      , Binomial[n - 1, k - 1]]][[2, 1]] 
  ]
```

Now for a test:

```
main[4, 2]

{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}}
```

Or:

```
main[6, 3]

{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 5, 6}}, {{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 
   6}}, {{1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 6}}, {{1, 3, 
   5}, {2, 4, 6}}, {{1, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}}, {{1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 
   6}}, {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 5}}, {{1, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4}}}
```

Or:

```
main[6, 2]

{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 
   6}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 2}, {4, 5}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {4, 6}, {3, 
   5}}, {{1, 2}, {5, 6}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 
   3}, {2, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 3}, {4, 5}, {2,
    6}}, {{1, 3}, {4, 6}, {2, 5}}, {{1, 3}, {5, 6}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 
   4}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 6}, {3,
    5}}, {{1, 4}, {3, 5}, {2, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {3, 6}, {2, 5}}, {{1, 
   4}, {5, 6}, {2, 3}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3,
    6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 5}, {3, 4}, {2, 6}}, {{1, 
   5}, {3, 6}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 5}, {4, 6}, {2, 3}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4,
    5}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 
   6}, {3, 4}, {2, 5}}, {{1, 6}, {3, 5}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 6}, {4, 5}, {2,
    3}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the function you defined show all the possible combinations, now I need to sort out just the ones where the subsets doesn't contain two elements that were presents in the previous subsets configurations. E.g. with $ main[6,3] $, I would just expect $\{$ $\{1, 2, 3\}$, $\{4, 5, 6\}$ $\}$, because it's not possible to find other subsets with $ 3 $ elements not containing $ 2 $ elements that were already present in one of the two starting subsets. I hope I explained my request. Thank you

Comment: I found out that sometimes the answer is redundant, I mean with $main[6,2]$ the output contains $2$ times {{1, 2}, {4, 6}, {3, 
   5}} and all the other sublists (they should be 15 and not 30)

Comment: I can not verify this, I get 30 lists. Try with a fresh kernel.

Comment: Yep but among them you get ...{{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {4, 6}, {3, 5}}..., which is basically the same. Don't worry, I same what fixed that

Answer (score 0):

I define `permutationsNk[n,k]` for `Integer` arguments, where `k` divides into `n` (or, alternatively, where `k` belongs to the `Divisors` of `n`).

Evaluating eg. `res=permutationsNk[4,2]` returns

[image]

Looking inside the [`Iconize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Iconize.html)d object, one finds

```
res // First
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Following along, down the depth of the result, one finds that the first iconized sub-element (of the top-level result) evaluates to

```
res // First/*(Part[#, 1] &)/*First
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

which can be further shown to be

```
res // First/*(Part[#, 1] &)/*First/*(Part[#, 1] &)/*First
```

[image]

Similarly, the second and third iconized sub-elements of the top-level result evaluate to

[image]
and
[image]
respectively.

It might have been easier or more convenient to evaluate the result all at once, using something like

```
res // First/*Map[First/*Map[First]]/*Apply[Join]
```

[image]

however, the results for the general case ($n$ and $k$ integers and $k|n$) can be *too many* in number and an approach like the one above, might temporarily freeze or hang the notebook.

It's not to say that accessing the results in a piecemeal fashion, is a definite workaround for the problem of the combinatorial explosion in the number of the results, however it seems to help, for *reasonable* input arguments (however, I haven't tried anything above $n=20$, so I could be wrong for even moderate values of $n$, but I'm confident that it's not the case).

Just to provide *another* **example**, evaluating `res=permutationsNk[8,4]` and using the bulk way (the one-liner presented above) to access the results (again, which *might* cause trouble with *larger* values for $n$) returns

[image]

Before providing the code, I will produce another example for the case `permutations[12,6]`, only this time the result is provided in plain text format and can be used for testing purposes:

```
permutations[12,6]
```

evaluates to

```
{{{1,2,3,4,5,6},{2,3,4,5,6,7},{3,4,5,6,7,8},{4,5,6,7,8,9},{5,6,7,8,9,10},{6,7,8,9,10,11},{7,8,9,10,11,12}},{{1,2,3,4,5,7},{2,3,4,5,6,8},{3,4,5,6,7,9},{4,5,6,7,8,10},{5,6,7,8,9,11},{6,7,8,9,10,12}},{{1,2,3,4,6,7},{2,3,4,5,7,8},{3,4,5,6,8,9},{4,5,6,7,9,10},{5,6,7,8,10,11},{6,7,8,9,11,12}},{{1,2,3,5,6,7},{2,3,4,6,7,8},{3,4,5,7,8,9},{4,5,6,8,9,10},{5,6,7,9,10,11},{6,7,8,10,11,12}},{{1,2,4,5,6,7},{2,3,5,6,7,8},{3,4,6,7,8,9},{4,5,7,8,9,10},{5,6,8,9,10,11},{6,7,9,10,11,12}},{{1,3,4,5,6,7},{2,4,5,6,7,8},{3,5,6,7,8,9},{4,6,7,8,9,10},{5,7,8,9,10,11},{6,8,9,10,11,12}},{{1,2,3,4,5,8},{2,3,4,5,6,9},{3,4,5,6,7,10},{4,5,6,7,8,11},{5,6,7,8,9,12}},{{1,2,3,4,6,8},{2,3,4,5,7,9},{3,4,5,6,8,10},{4,5,6,7,9,11},{5,6,7,8,10,12}},{{1,2,3,4,7,8},{2,3,4,5,8,9},{3,4,5,6,9,10},{4,5,6,7,10,11},{5,6,7,8,11,12}},{{1,2,3,5,6,8},{2,3,4,6,7,9},{3,4,5,7,8,10},{4,5,6,8,9,11},{5,6,7,9,10,12}},{{1,2,3,5,7,8},{2,3,4,6,8,9},{3,4,5,7,9,10},{4,5,6,8,10,11},{5,6,7,9,11,12}},{{1,2,3,6,7,8},{2,3,4,7,8,9},{3,4,5,8,9,10},{4,5,6,9,10,11},{5,6,7,10,11,12}},{{1,2,4,5,6,8},{2,3,5,6,7,9},{3,4,6,7,8,10},{4,5,7,8,9,11},{5,6,8,9,10,12}},{{1,2,4,5,7,8},{2,3,5,6,8,9},{3,4,6,7,9,10},{4,5,7,8,10,11},{5,6,8,9,11,12}},{{1,2,4,6,7,8},{2,3,5,7,8,9},{3,4,6,8,9,10},{4,5,7,9,10,11},{5,6,8,10,11,12}},{{1,2,5,6,7,8},{2,3,6,7,8,9},{3,4,7,8,9,10},{4,5,8,9,10,11},{5,6,9,10,11,12}},{{1,3,4,5,6,8},{2,4,5,6,7,9},{3,5,6,7,8,10},{4,6,7,8,9,11},{5,7,8,9,10,12}},{{1,3,4,5,7,8},{2,4,5,6,8,9},{3,5,6,7,9,10},{4,6,7,8,10,11},{5,7,8,9,11,12}},{{1,3,4,6,7,8},{2,4,5,7,8,9},{3,5,6,8,9,10},{4,6,7,9,10,11},{5,7,8,10,11,12}},{{1,3,5,6,7,8},{2,4,6,7,8,9},{3,5,7,8,9,10},{4,6,8,9,10,11},{5,7,9,10,11,12}},{{1,4,5,6,7,8},{2,5,6,7,8,9},{3,6,7,8,9,10},{4,7,8,9,10,11},{5,8,9,10,11,12}},{{1,2,3,4,5,9},{2,3,4,5,6,10},{3,4,5,6,7,11},{4,5,6,7,8,12}},{{1,2,3,4,6,9},{2,3,4,5,7,10},{3,4,5,6,8,11},{4,5,6,7,9,12}},{{1,2,3,4,7,9},{2,3,4,5,8,10},{3,4,5,6,9,11},{4,5,6,7,10,12}},{{1,2,3,4,8,9},{2,3,4,5,9,10},{3,4,5,6,10,11},{4,5,6,7,11,12}},{{1,2,3,5,6,9},{2,3,4,6,7,10},{3,4,5,7,8,11},{4,5,6,8,9,12}},{{1,2,3,5,7,9},{2,3,4,6,8,10},{3,4,5,7,9,11},{4,5,6,8,10,12}},{{1,2,3,5,8,9},{2,3,4,6,9,10},{3,4,5,7,10,11},{4,5,6,8,11,12}},{{1,2,3,6,7,9},{2,3,4,7,8,10},{3,4,5,8,9,11},{4,5,6,9,10,12}},{{1,2,3,6,8,9},{2,3,4,7,9,10},{3,4,5,8,10,11},{4,5,6,9,11,12}},{{1,2,3,7,8,9},{2,3,4,8,9,10},{3,4,5,9,10,11},{4,5,6,10,11,12}},{{1,2,4,5,6,9},{2,3,5,6,7,10},{3,4,6,7,8,11},{4,5,7,8,9,12}},{{1,2,4,5,7,9},{2,3,5,6,8,10},{3,4,6,7,9,11},{4,5,7,8,10,12}},{{1,2,4,5,8,9},{2,3,5,6,9,10},{3,4,6,7,10,11},{4,5,7,8,11,12}},{{1,2,4,6,7,9},{2,3,5,7,8,10},{3,4,6,8,9,11},{4,5,7,9,10,12}},{{1,2,4,6,8,9},{2,3,5,7,9,10},{3,4,6,8,10,11},{4,5,7,9,11,12}},{{1,2,4,7,8,9},{2,3,5,8,9,10},{3,4,6,9,10,11},{4,5,7,10,11,12}},{{1,2,5,6,7,9},{2,3,6,7,8,10},{3,4,7,8,9,11},{4,5,8,9,10,12}},{{1,2,5,6,8,9},{2,3,6,7,9,10},{3,4,7,8,10,11},{4,5,8,9,11,12}},{{1,2,5,7,8,9},{2,3,6,8,9,10},{3,4,7,9,10,11},{4,5,8,10,11,12}},{{1,2,6,7,8,9},{2,3,7,8,9,10},{3,4,8,9,10,11},{4,5,9,10,11,12}},{{1,3,4,5,6,9},{2,4,5,6,7,10},{3,5,6,7,8,11},{4,6,7,8,9,12}},{{1,3,4,5,7,9},{2,4,5,6,8,10},{3,5,6,7,9,11},{4,6,7,8,10,12}},{{1,3,4,5,8,9},{2,4,5,6,9,10},{3,5,6,7,10,11},{4,6,7,8,11,12}},{{1,3,4,6,7,9},{2,4,5,7,8,10},{3,5,6,8,9,11},{4,6,7,9,10,12}},{{1,3,4,6,8,9},{2,4,5,7,9,10},{3,5,6,8,10,11},{4,6,7,9,11,12}},{{1,3,4,7,8,9},{2,4,5,8,9,10},{3,5,6,9,10,11},{4,6,7,10,11,12}},{{1,3,5,6,7,9},{2,4,6,7,8,10},{3,5,7,8,9,11},{4,6,8,9,10,12}},{{1,3,5,6,8,9},{2,4,6,7,9,10},{3,5,7,8,10,11},{4,6,8,9,11,12}},{{1,3,5,7,8,9},{2,4,6,8,9,10},{3,5,7,9,10,11},{4,6,8,10,11,12}},{{1,3,6,7,8,9},{2,4,7,8,9,10},{3,5,8,9,10,11},{4,6,9,10,11,12}},{{1,4,5,6,7,9},{2,5,6,7,8,10},{3,6,7,8,9,11},{4,7,8,9,10,12}},{{1,4,5,6,8,9},{2,5,6,7,9,10},{3,6,7,8,10,11},{4,7,8,9,11,12}},{{1,4,5,7,8,9},{2,5,6,8,9,10},{3,6,7,9,10,11},{4,7,8,10,11,12}},{{1,4,6,7,8,9},{2,5,7,8,9,10},{3,6,8,9,10,11},{4,7,9,10,11,12}},{{1,5,6,7,8,9},{2,6,7,8,9,10},{3,7,8,9,10,11},{4,8,9,10,11,12}},{{1,2,3,4,5,10},{2,3,4,5,6,11},{3,4,5,6,7,12}},{{1,2,3,4,6,10},{2,3,4,5,7,11},{3,4,5,6,8,12}},{{1,2,3,4,7,10},{2,3,4,5,8,11},{3,4,5,6,9,12}},{{1,2,3,4,8,10},{2,3,4,5,9,11},{3,4,5,6,10,12}},{{1,2,3,4,9,10},{2,3,4,5,10,11},{3,4,5,6,11,12}},{{1,2,3,5,6,10},{2,3,4,6,7,11},{3,4,5,7,8,12}},{{1,2,3,5,7,10},{2,3,4,6,8,11},{3,4,5,7,9,12}},{{1,2,3,5,8,10},{2,3,4,6,9,11},{3,4,5,7,10,12}},{{1,2,3,5,9,10},{2,3,4,6,10,11},{3,4,5,7,11,12}},{{1,2,3,6,7,10},{2,3,4,7,8,11},{3,4,5,8,9,12}},{{1,2,3,6,8,10},{2,3,4,7,9,11},{3,4,5,8,10,12}},{{1,2,3,6,9,10},{2,3,4,7,10,11},{3,4,5,8,11,12}},{{1,2,3,7,8,10},{2,3,4,8,9,11},{3,4,5,9,10,12}},{{1,2,3,7,9,10},{2,3,4,8,10,11},{3,4,5,9,11,12}},{{1,2,3,8,9,10},{2,3,4,9,10,11},{3,4,5,10,11,12}},{{1,2,4,5,6,10},{2,3,5,6,7,11},{3,4,6,7,8,12}},{{1,2,4,5,7,10},{2,3,5,6,8,11},{3,4,6,7,9,12}},{{1,2,4,5,8,10},{2,3,5,6,9,11},{3,4,6,7,10,12}},{{1,2,4,5,9,10},{2,3,5,6,10,11},{3,4,6,7,11,12}},{{1,2,4,6,7,10},{2,3,5,7,8,11},{3,4,6,8,9,12}},{{1,2,4,6,8,10},{2,3,5,7,9,11},{3,4,6,8,10,12}},{{1,2,4,6,9,10},{2,3,5,7,10,11},{3,4,6,8,11,12}},{{1,2,4,7,8,10},{2,3,5,8,9,11},{3,4,6,9,10,12}},{{1,2,4,7,9,10},{2,3,5,8,10,11},{3,4,6,9,11,12}},{{1,2,4,8,9,10},{2,3,5,9,10,11},{3,4,6,10,11,12}},{{1,2,5,6,7,10},{2,3,6,7,8,11},{3,4,7,8,9,12}},{{1,2,5,6,8,10},{2,3,6,7,9,11},{3,4,7,8,10,12}},{{1,2,5,6,9,10},{2,3,6,7,10,11},{3,4,7,8,11,12}},{{1,2,5,7,8,10},{2,3,6,8,9,11},{3,4,7,9,10,12}},{{1,2,5,7,9,10},{2,3,6,8,10,11},{3,4,7,9,11,12}},{{1,2,5,8,9,10},{2,3,6,9,10,11},{3,4,7,10,11,12}},{{1,2,6,7,8,10},{2,3,7,8,9,11},{3,4,8,9,10,12}},{{1,2,6,7,9,10},{2,3,7,8,10,11},{3,4,8,9,11,12}},{{1,2,6,8,9,10},{2,3,7,9,10,11},{3,4,8,10,11,12}},{{1,2,7,8,9,10},{2,3,8,9,10,11},{3,4,9,10,11,12}},{{1,3,4,5,6,10},{2,4,5,6,7,11},{3,5,6,7,8,12}},{{1,3,4,5,7,10},{2,4,5,6,8,11},{3,5,6,7,9,12}},{{1,3,4,5,8,10},{2,4,5,6,9,11},{3,5,6,7,10,12}},{{1,3,4,5,9,10},{2,4,5,6,10,11},{3,5,6,7,11,12}},{{1,3,4,6,7,10},{2,4,5,7,8,11},{3,5,6,8,9,12}},{{1,3,4,6,8,10},{2,4,5,7,9,11},{3,5,6,8,10,12}},{{1,3,4,6,9,10},{2,4,5,7,10,11},{3,5,6,8,11,12}},{{1,3,4,7,8,10},{2,4,5,8,9,11},{3,5,6,9,10,12}},{{1,3,4,7,9,10},{2,4,5,8,10,11},{3,5,6,9,11,12}},{{1,3,4,8,9,10},{2,4,5,9,10,11},{3,5,6,10,11,12}},{{1,3,5,6,7,10},{2,4,6,7,8,11},{3,5,7,8,9,12}},{{1,3,5,6,8,10},{2,4,6,7,9,11},{3,5,7,8,10,12}},{{1,3,5,6,9,10},{2,4,6,7,10,11},{3,5,7,8,11,12}},{{1,3,5,7,8,10},{2,4,6,8,9,11},{3,5,7,9,10,12}},{{1,3,5,7,9,10},{2,4,6,8,10,11},{3,5,7,9,11,12}},{{1,3,5,8,9,10},{2,4,6,9,10,11},{3,5,7,10,11,12}},{{1,3,6,7,8,10},{2,4,7,8,9,11},{3,5,8,9,10,12}},{{1,3,6,7,9,10},{2,4,7,8,10,11},{3,5,8,9,11,12}},{{1,3,6,8,9,10},{2,4,7,9,10,11},{3,5,8,10,11,12}},{{1,3,7,8,9,10},{2,4,8,9,10,11},{3,5,9,10,11,12}},{{1,4,5,6,7,10},{2,5,6,7,8,11},{3,6,7,8,9,12}},{{1,4,5,6,8,10},{2,5,6,7,9,11},{3,6,7,8,10,12}},{{1,4,5,6,9,10},{2,5,6,7,10,11},{3,6,7,8,11,12}},{{1,4,5,7,8,10},{2,5,6,8,9,11},{3,6,7,9,10,12}},{{1,4,5,7,9,10},{2,5,6,8,10,11},{3,6,7,9,11,12}},{{1,4,5,8,9,10},{2,5,6,9,10,11},{3,6,7,10,11,12}},{{1,4,6,7,8,10},{2,5,7,8,9,11},{3,6,8,9,10,12}},{{1,4,6,7,9,10},{2,5,7,8,10,11},{3,6,8,9,11,12}},{{1,4,6,8,9,10},{2,5,7,9,10,11},{3,6,8,10,11,12}},{{1,4,7,8,9,10},{2,5,8,9,10,11},{3,6,9,10,11,12}},{{1,5,6,7,8,10},{2,6,7,8,9,11},{3,7,8,9,10,12}},{{1,5,6,7,9,10},{2,6,7,8,10,11},{3,7,8,9,11,12}},{{1,5,6,8,9,10},{2,6,7,9,10,11},{3,7,8,10,11,12}},{{1,5,7,8,9,10},{2,6,8,9,10,11},{3,7,9,10,11,12}},{{1,6,7,8,9,10},{2,7,8,9,10,11},{3,8,9,10,11,12}},{{1,2,3,4,5,11},{2,3,4,5,6,12}},{{1,2,3,4,6,11},{2,3,4,5,7,12}},{{1,2,3,4,7,11},{2,3,4,5,8,12}},{{1,2,3,4,8,11},{2,3,4,5,9,12}},{{1,2,3,4,9,11},{2,3,4,5,10,12}},{{1,2,3,4,10,11},{2,3,4,5,11,12}},{{1,2,3,5,6,11},{2,3,4,6,7,12}},{{1,2,3,5,7,11},{2,3,4,6,8,12}},{{1,2,3,5,8,11},{2,3,4,6,9,12}},{{1,2,3,5,9,11},{2,3,4,6,10,12}},{{1,2,3,5,10,11},{2,3,4,6,11,12}},{{1,2,3,6,7,11},{2,3,4,7,8,12}},{{1,2,3,6,8,11},{2,3,4,7,9,12}},{{1,2,3,6,9,11},{2,3,4,7,10,12}},{{1,2,3,6,10,11},{2,3,4,7,11,12}},{{1,2,3,7,8,11},{2,3,4,8,9,12}},{{1,2,3,7,9,11},{2,3,4,8,10,12}},{{1,2,3,7,10,11},{2,3,4,8,11,12}},{{1,2,3,8,9,11},{2,3,4,9,10,12}},{{1,2,3,8,10,11},{2,3,4,9,11,12}},{{1,2,3,9,10,11},{2,3,4,10,11,12}},{{1,2,4,5,6,11},{2,3,5,6,7,12}},{{1,2,4,5,7,11},{2,3,5,6,8,12}},{{1,2,4,5,8,11},{2,3,5,6,9,12}},{{1,2,4,5,9,11},{2,3,5,6,10,12}},{{1,2,4,5,10,11},{2,3,5,6,11,12}},{{1,2,4,6,7,11},{2,3,5,7,8,12}},{{1,2,4,6,8,11},{2,3,5,7,9,12}},{{1,2,4,6,9,11},{2,3,5,7,10,12}},{{1,2,4,6,10,11},{2,3,5,7,11,12}},{{1,2,4,7,8,11},{2,3,5,8,9,12}},{{1,2,4,7,9,11},{2,3,5,8,10,12}},{{1,2,4,7,10,11},{2,3,5,8,11,12}},{{1,2,4,8,9,11},{2,3,5,9,10,12}},{{1,2,4,8,10,11},{2,3,5,9,11,12}},{{1,2,4,9,10,11},{2,3,5,10,11,12}},{{1,2,5,6,7,11},{2,3,6,7,8,12}},{{1,2,5,6,8,11},{2,3,6,7,9,12}},{{1,2,5,6,9,11},{2,3,6,7,10,12}},{{1,2,5,6,10,11},{2,3,6,7,11,12}},{{1,2,5,7,8,11},{2,3,6,8,9,12}},{{1,2,5,7,9,11},{2,3,6,8,10,12}},{{1,2,5,7,10,11},{2,3,6,8,11,12}},{{1,2,5,8,9,11},{2,3,6,9,10,12}},{{1,2,5,8,10,11},{2,3,6,9,11,12}},{{1,2,5,9,10,11},{2,3,6,10,11,12}},{{1,2,6,7,8,11},{2,3,7,8,9,12}},{{1,2,6,7,9,11},{2,3,7,8,10,12}},{{1,2,6,7,10,11},{2,3,7,8,11,12}},{{1,2,6,8,9,11},{2,3,7,9,10,12}},{{1,2,6,8,10,11},{2,3,7,9,11,12}},{{1,2,6,9,10,11},{2,3,7,10,11,12}},{{1,2,7,8,9,11},{2,3,8,9,10,12}},{{1,2,7,8,10,11},{2,3,8,9,11,12}},{{1,2,7,9,10,11},{2,3,8,10,11,12}},{{1,2,8,9,10,11},{2,3,9,10,11,12}},{{1,3,4,5,6,11},{2,4,5,6,7,12}},{{1,3,4,5,7,11},{2,4,5,6,8,12}},{{1,3,4,5,8,11},{2,4,5,6,9,12}},{{1,3,4,5,9,11},{2,4,5,6,10,12}},{{1,3,4,5,10,11},{2,4,5,6,11,12}},{{1,3,4,6,7,11},{2,4,5,7,8,12}},{{1,3,4,6,8,11},{2,4,5,7,9,12}},{{1,3,4,6,9,11},{2,4,5,7,10,12}},{{1,3,4,6,10,11},{2,4,5,7,11,12}},{{1,3,4,7,8,11},{2,4,5,8,9,12}},{{1,3,4,7,9,11},{2,4,5,8,10,12}},{{1,3,4,7,10,11},{2,4,5,8,11,12}},{{1,3,4,8,9,11},{2,4,5,9,10,12}},{{1,3,4,8,10,11},{2,4,5,9,11,12}},{{1,3,4,9,10,11},{2,4,5,10,11,12}},{{1,3,5,6,7,11},{2,4,6,7,8,12}},{{1,3,5,6,8,11},{2,4,6,7,9,12}},{{1,3,5,6,9,11},{2,4,6,7,10,12}},{{1,3,5,6,10,11},{2,4,6,7,11,12}},{{1,3,5,7,8,11},{2,4,6,8,9,12}},{{1,3,5,7,9,11},{2,4,6,8,10,12}},{{1,3,5,7,10,11},{2,4,6,8,11,12}},{{1,3,5,8,9,11},{2,4,6,9,10,12}},{{1,3,5,8,10,11},{2,4,6,9,11,12}},{{1,3,5,9,10,11},{2,4,6,10,11,12}},{{1,3,6,7,8,11},{2,4,7,8,9,12}},{{1,3,6,7,9,11},{2,4,7,8,10,12}},{{1,3,6,7,10,11},{2,4,7,8,11,12}},{{1,3,6,8,9,11},{2,4,7,9,10,12}},{{1,3,6,8,10,11},{2,4,7,9,11,12}},{{1,3,6,9,10,11},{2,4,7,10,11,12}},{{1,3,7,8,9,11},{2,4,8,9,10,12}},{{1,3,7,8,10,11},{2,4,8,9,11,12}},{{1,3,7,9,10,11},{2,4,8,10,11,12}},{{1,3,8,9,10,11},{2,4,9,10,11,12}},{{1,4,5,6,7,11},{2,5,6,7,8,12}},{{1,4,5,6,8,11},{2,5,6,7,9,12}},{{1,4,5,6,9,11},{2,5,6,7,10,12}},{{1,4,5,6,10,11},{2,5,6,7,11,12}},{{1,4,5,7,8,11},{2,5,6,8,9,12}},{{1,4,5,7,9,11},{2,5,6,8,10,12}},{{1,4,5,7,10,11},{2,5,6,8,11,12}},{{1,4,5,8,9,11},{2,5,6,9,10,12}},{{1,4,5,8,10,11},{2,5,6,9,11,12}},{{1,4,5,9,10,11},{2,5,6,10,11,12}},{{1,4,6,7,8,11},{2,5,7,8,9,12}},{{1,4,6,7,9,11},{2,5,7,8,10,12}},{{1,4,6,7,10,11},{2,5,7,8,11,12}},{{1,4,6,8,9,11},{2,5,7,9,10,12}},{{1,4,6,8,10,11},{2,5,7,9,11,12}},{{1,4,6,9,10,11},{2,5,7,10,11,12}},{{1,4,7,8,9,11},{2,5,8,9,10,12}},{{1,4,7,8,10,11},{2,5,8,9,11,12}},{{1,4,7,9,10,11},{2,5,8,10,11,12}},{{1,4,8,9,10,11},{2,5,9,10,11,12}},{{1,5,6,7,8,11},{2,6,7,8,9,12}},{{1,5,6,7,9,11},{2,6,7,8,10,12}},{{1,5,6,7,10,11},{2,6,7,8,11,12}},{{1,5,6,8,9,11},{2,6,7,9,10,12}},{{1,5,6,8,10,11},{2,6,7,9,11,12}},{{1,5,6,9,10,11},{2,6,7,10,11,12}},{{1,5,7,8,9,11},{2,6,8,9,10,12}},{{1,5,7,8,10,11},{2,6,8,9,11,12}},{{1,5,7,9,10,11},{2,6,8,10,11,12}},{{1,5,8,9,10,11},{2,6,9,10,11,12}},{{1,6,7,8,9,11},{2,7,8,9,10,12}},{{1,6,7,8,10,11},{2,7,8,9,11,12}},{{1,6,7,9,10,11},{2,7,8,10,11,12}},{{1,6,8,9,10,11},{2,7,9,10,11,12}},{{1,7,8,9,10,11},{2,8,9,10,11,12}},{{1,2,3,4,5,12}},{{1,2,3,4,6,12}},{{1,2,3,4,7,12}},{{1,2,3,4,8,12}},{{1,2,3,4,9,12}},{{1,2,3,4,10,12}},{{1,2,3,4,11,12}},{{1,2,3,5,6,12}},{{1,2,3,5,7,12}},{{1,2,3,5,8,12}},{{1,2,3,5,9,12}},{{1,2,3,5,10,12}},{{1,2,3,5,11,12}},{{1,2,3,6,7,12}},{{1,2,3,6,8,12}},{{1,2,3,6,9,12}},{{1,2,3,6,10,12}},{{1,2,3,6,11,12}},{{1,2,3,7,8,12}},{{1,2,3,7,9,12}},{{1,2,3,7,10,12}},{{1,2,3,7,11,12}},{{1,2,3,8,9,12}},{{1,2,3,8,10,12}},{{1,2,3,8,11,12}},{{1,2,3,9,10,12}},{{1,2,3,9,11,12}},{{1,2,3,10,11,12}},{{1,2,4,5,6,12}},{{1,2,4,5,7,12}},{{1,2,4,5,8,12}},{{1,2,4,5,9,12}},{{1,2,4,5,10,12}},{{1,2,4,5,11,12}},{{1,2,4,6,7,12}},{{1,2,4,6,8,12}},{{1,2,4,6,9,12}},{{1,2,4,6,10,12}},{{1,2,4,6,11,12}},{{1,2,4,7,8,12}},{{1,2,4,7,9,12}},{{1,2,4,7,10,12}},{{1,2,4,7,11,12}},{{1,2,4,8,9,12}},{{1,2,4,8,10,12}},{{1,2,4,8,11,12}},{{1,2,4,9,10,12}},{{1,2,4,9,11,12}},{{1,2,4,10,11,12}},{{1,2,5,6,7,12}},{{1,2,5,6,8,12}},{{1,2,5,6,9,12}},{{1,2,5,6,10,12}},{{1,2,5,6,11,12}},{{1,2,5,7,8,12}},{{1,2,5,7,9,12}},{{1,2,5,7,10,12}},{{1,2,5,7,11,12}},{{1,2,5,8,9,12}},{{1,2,5,8,10,12}},{{1,2,5,8,11,12}},{{1,2,5,9,10,12}},{{1,2,5,9,11,12}},{{1,2,5,10,11,12}},{{1,2,6,7,8,12}},{{1,2,6,7,9,12}},{{1,2,6,7,10,12}},{{1,2,6,7,11,12}},{{1,2,6,8,9,12}},{{1,2,6,8,10,12}},{{1,2,6,8,11,12}},{{1,2,6,9,10,12}},{{1,2,6,9,11,12}},{{1,2,6,10,11,12}},{{1,2,7,8,9,12}},{{1,2,7,8,10,12}},{{1,2,7,8,11,12}},{{1,2,7,9,10,12}},{{1,2,7,9,11,12}},{{1,2,7,10,11,12}},{{1,2,8,9,10,12}},{{1,2,8,9,11,12}},{{1,2,8,10,11,12}},{{1,2,9,10,11,12}},{{1,3,4,5,6,12}},{{1,3,4,5,7,12}},{{1,3,4,5,8,12}},{{1,3,4,5,9,12}},{{1,3,4,5,10,12}},{{1,3,4,5,11,12}},{{1,3,4,6,7,12}},{{1,3,4,6,8,12}},{{1,3,4,6,9,12}},{{1,3,4,6,10,12}},{{1,3,4,6,11,12}},{{1,3,4,7,8,12}},{{1,3,4,7,9,12}},{{1,3,4,7,10,12}},{{1,3,4,7,11,12}},{{1,3,4,8,9,12}},{{1,3,4,8,10,12}},{{1,3,4,8,11,12}},{{1,3,4,9,10,12}},{{1,3,4,9,11,12}},{{1,3,4,10,11,12}},{{1,3,5,6,7,12}},{{1,3,5,6,8,12}},{{1,3,5,6,9,12}},{{1,3,5,6,10,12}},{{1,3,5,6,11,12}},{{1,3,5,7,8,12}},{{1,3,5,7,9,12}},{{1,3,5,7,10,12}},{{1,3,5,7,11,12}},{{1,3,5,8,9,12}},{{1,3,5,8,10,12}},{{1,3,5,8,11,12}},{{1,3,5,9,10,12}},{{1,3,5,9,11,12}},{{1,3,5,10,11,12}},{{1,3,6,7,8,12}},{{1,3,6,7,9,12}},{{1,3,6,7,10,12}},{{1,3,6,7,11,12}},{{1,3,6,8,9,12}},{{1,3,6,8,10,12}},{{1,3,6,8,11,12}},{{1,3,6,9,10,12}},{{1,3,6,9,11,12}},{{1,3,6,10,11,12}},{{1,3,7,8,9,12}},{{1,3,7,8,10,12}},{{1,3,7,8,11,12}},{{1,3,7,9,10,12}},{{1,3,7,9,11,12}},{{1,3,7,10,11,12}},{{1,3,8,9,10,12}},{{1,3,8,9,11,12}},{{1,3,8,10,11,12}},{{1,3,9,10,11,12}},{{1,4,5,6,7,12}},{{1,4,5,6,8,12}},{{1,4,5,6,9,12}},{{1,4,5,6,10,12}},{{1,4,5,6,11,12}},{{1,4,5,7,8,12}},{{1,4,5,7,9,12}},{{1,4,5,7,10,12}},{{1,4,5,7,11,12}},{{1,4,5,8,9,12}},{{1,4,5,8,10,12}},{{1,4,5,8,11,12}},{{1,4,5,9,10,12}},{{1,4,5,9,11,12}},{{1,4,5,10,11,12}},{{1,4,6,7,8,12}},{{1,4,6,7,9,12}},{{1,4,6,7,10,12}},{{1,4,6,7,11,12}},{{1,4,6,8,9,12}},{{1,4,6,8,10,12}},{{1,4,6,8,11,12}},{{1,4,6,9,10,12}},{{1,4,6,9,11,12}},{{1,4,6,10,11,12}},{{1,4,7,8,9,12}},{{1,4,7,8,10,12}},{{1,4,7,8,11,12}},{{1,4,7,9,10,12}},{{1,4,7,9,11,12}},{{1,4,7,10,11,12}},{{1,4,8,9,10,12}},{{1,4,8,9,11,12}},{{1,4,8,10,11,12}},{{1,4,9,10,11,12}},{{1,5,6,7,8,12}},{{1,5,6,7,9,12}},{{1,5,6,7,10,12}},{{1,5,6,7,11,12}},{{1,5,6,8,9,12}},{{1,5,6,8,10,12}},{{1,5,6,8,11,12}},{{1,5,6,9,10,12}},{{1,5,6,9,11,12}},{{1,5,6,10,11,12}},{{1,5,7,8,9,12}},{{1,5,7,8,10,12}},{{1,5,7,8,11,12}},{{1,5,7,9,10,12}},{{1,5,7,9,11,12}},{{1,5,7,10,11,12}},{{1,5,8,9,10,12}},{{1,5,8,9,11,12}},{{1,5,8,10,11,12}},{{1,5,9,10,11,12}},{{1,6,7,8,9,12}},{{1,6,7,8,10,12}},{{1,6,7,8,11,12}},{{1,6,7,9,10,12}},{{1,6,7,9,11,12}},{{1,6,7,10,11,12}},{{1,6,8,9,10,12}},{{1,6,8,9,11,12}},{{1,6,8,10,11,12}},{{1,6,9,10,11,12}},{{1,7,8,9,10,12}},{{1,7,8,9,11,12}},{{1,7,8,10,11,12}},{{1,7,9,10,11,12}},{{1,8,9,10,11,12}}}
```

---

### Definitions

The following definitions are mostly user interface definitions:

```
ClearAll[permutationsNk, doPermutationsNk]
permutationsNk[n_?IntegerQ,k_?IntegerQ]/;Mod[n,k]==0:=doPermutationsNk[n,k]
```

Here we define the messages generated from erroneous user input:

```
permutationsNk::notint="`1` is not an Integer";
permutationsNk[x_?(IntegerQ/*Not),y_?IntegerQ]:=(Message[permutationsNk::notint,x])
permutationsNk[x_?IntegerQ,y_?(IntegerQ/*Not)]:=(Message[permutationsNk::notint,y])

permutationsNk::badargs="`2` does not divide into `1`, exactly";
permutationsNk[x_,y_]:=(Message[permutationsNk::badargs,x,y])
```

This is essentially what drives the results: The way to combine different elements of the list `{1,2,...,n}` is done through [`ListCorrelate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate.html). The *auxiliary* function `times` combines the entries in the kernel (`ker`, ones or zeros) with the numbers in `list` (`{1,2,...,n}`). Whenever it encounters a zero in the kernel, it evaluates to [`Nothing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html). This behavior, coupled with the fact that the last argument of `ListCorrelate` is `List` allows for the construction of the desirable tuples.

```
Clear[times,listCorrelate]
times=(Switch[#1,0,Nothing,_,Times[##]]&);
listCorrelate[ker_,list_]:=ListCorrelate[ker,list,{1,-1},{},times,List]
```

An example for how `listCorrelate` works, consider a kernel `ker={a,0,b}` and `list=Range[4]`:

```
listCorrelate[{a,0,b},Range[4]]
```

[image]

Whenever a zero is encountered in the kernel, `Nothing` is returned, which in turn is wrapped in a list eg `{a,Nothing,3b}` which simplifies to `{a,3b}`.

Putting everything together:

```
doPermutationsNk[n_,k_]:=Module[{ker,list,firstLL,lastLL,reMo,ico,null,res,permutations,outer,apply,through,res0},
  ker=ConstantArray[1,k];
  list=Range[n];

  firstLL=First/*List/*List;
  lastLL=Last/*List/*List;
  reMo=Rest/*Most;
  ico=Iconize[#1,ToString[#2]]&;

  permutations[j_]:=(Join[#,ConstantArray[0,j]]&)/*Permutations;
  outer[j_,args__]:=Outer[Join/*(listCorrelate[#,list]&)/*(ico[#,j]&),args,1];
  apply[j_]:=(With[{len=Length[{##}]},outer[j,##]//(Flatten[#,len-1]&)]&)/*(ico[#,Length[#]]&);
  through[j_]:={firstLL,reMo/*permutations[j],lastLL};

  {null,{res}}=Reap@Do[ker//(Through[through[j][#]]&)/*Apply[apply[j]]/*Sow,{j,n-k}];

  res0=listCorrelate[ConstantArray[1,k],list]//(ico[#,Length[#]]&)/*List/*(ico[#,Length[#]]&);
  Join[{res0},res]//(ico[#,Length[#]]&)
]
```

The following two expressions deal with boundary values for $k$:

```
doPermutationsNk[n_,1]:=Module[{list,ico,res0},
  list=Range[n];

  ico=Iconize[#1,ToString[#2]]&;

  res0=list//List/*Transpose/*(ico[#,Length[#]]&)/*List/*(ico[#,Length[#]]&);
  Join[{res0},{}]//(ico[#,Length[#]]&)
]
```

and

```
doPermutationsNk[n_,n_]:=Module[{list,ico,res0},
  list=Range[n];

  ico=Iconize[#1,ToString[#2]]&;

  res0=list//List/*(ico[#,Length[#]]&)/*List/*(ico[#,Length[#]]&);
  Join[{res0},{}]//(ico[#,Length[#]]&)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

```
perm[set_List, k_Integer] := If[Length[set]<2k,
  List/@Subsets[set,{k}],
  Flatten[
    Function[s,Prepend[#,s]&/@perm[Complement[
     Drop[set,First@FirstPosition[set,First[s]]],s],k]]
     /@Subsets[set, {k}], 1]
  ];
perm[n_Integer, k_Integer] := perm[Range[n], k];
```

It might be not the most effective, but it is much faster than @Daniel's `main` function.

For  example,

```
In[1]:= Timing[perm[10, 2]]
Out[1]:= {0.1,{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}},...}}(*4260 elements*)
```