# Delete the subsets containing the same $2$ integers present in other subsets

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, permutation

From my [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279672/permutations-with-subsets-not-containing-the-same-elements), if I consider a list like this:

$\{$$\{$$\{$$1,2,3$$\}$,$\{$$4,5,6$$\}$$\}$,
$\{$$\{$$1,2,4$$\}$,$\{$$3,5,6$$\}$$\}$,
$\{$$\{$$1,2,5$$\}$,$\{$$3,4,6$$\}$$\}$,
$\{$$\{$$1,2,6$$\}$,$\{$$3,4,5$$\}$$\}$,
$\{$$\{$$1,3,4$$\}$,$\{$$2,5,6$$\}$$\}$,
$\{$$\{$$1,3,5$$\}$,$\{$$2,4,6$$\}$$\}$,
$\{$$\{$$1,3,6$$\}$,$\{$$2,4,5$$\}$$\}$,
$\{$$\{$$1,4,5$$\}$,$\{$$2,3,6$$\}$$\}$,
$\{$$\{$$1,4,6$$\}$,$\{$$2,3,5$$\}$$\}$,
$\{$$\{$$1,5,6$$\}$,$\{$$2,3,4$$\}$$\}$$\}$

how can I delete all the permuted sublists containing in one of their subset $2$ different integers already present in one of the subsets of the previous permuted sublists? I hope the request is clear.
In the showed case, the output would just be:

$\{$$\{$$1,2,3$$\}$,$\{$$4,5,6$$\}$$\}$

While considering the sublists of $6$ elements divided in subsets of length $2$, starting with

$\{$$\{$$1,2$$\}$,$\{$$3,4$$\}$,$\{$$5,6$$\}$$\}$

this one has to be deleted:

$\{$$\{$$1,3$$\}$,$\{$$2,4$$\}$,$\{$$5,6$$\}$$\}$

while this one (and others too) should be in the output:

$\{$$\{$$1,3$$\}$,$\{$$4,5$$\}$,$\{$$2,6$$\}$$\}$

Comment: With all due respect, I personally think it not quite clear ;).

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Sorry for that! I try with an example:
considering the list of 6 divided in subsets of length 2, starting with 
$\{$$\{$$1,2$$\}$,$\{$$3,4$$\}$,$\{$$5,6$$\}$$\}$

this one has to be deleted:
$\{$$\{$$1,3$$\}$,$\{$$2,4$$\}$,$\{$$5,6$$\}$$\}$

while this one should be in the output:
$\{$$\{$$1,3$$\}$,$\{$$4,5$$\}$,$\{$$2,6$$\}$$\}$

Comment: @user967210 perhaps you should add the second example so people have two expected results to cross-check. this will help to get a correct answer

Answer (score 2):

This works for the example you gave:

```
d = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 5, 6}}, {{1, 2, 5}, {3, 
      4, 6}}, {{1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 6}}, {{1, 3, 
      5}, {2, 4, 6}}, {{1, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}}, {{1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 
      6}}, {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 5}}, {{1, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4}}};;
i = 1;
While[++i <= Length[d],
If[Or @@ 
  Flatten[Outer[Length[Intersection[#1, #2]] > 1 &, 
    Flatten[d[[;; i - 1]], 1], d[[i]], 1]], d = Delete[d, i]; --i;]

  ];
d

{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}
```

or:

```
d = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 
     3}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}};
```

results in:

```
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 
   4}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}}
```

Comment: Thank you again. I tried with other example using your function $ main[6, 3] $ and the output is {{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}, {{1,3},{2,5},{4,6}},{{1,4},{2,3},{5,6}}, {{1,5},{2,4},{3,6}}, {{1,6},{2,3},{4,5}}}  so the first 2 and last 2 sublists are fine, but not the third one because the subset {5,6} was already present in the previous sublist and is missing {{1,4},{2,6},{3,5}}. I really appreciate your help, Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I misread:  "previous permuted sublist" and not "previous permuted sublists". I fixed this.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I looked for!

Answer (score 2):

You can use two-argument form of [`DeleteDuplicates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html):

```
ClearAll[cleanUp]

cleanUp = DeleteDuplicates[#, 
    GreaterThan[1] @ Max @ Outer[Length @* Intersection, ##, 1] &] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
d1 = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 5, 6}}, {{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 6}},
     {{1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 6}}, {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}}, 
     {{1, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}}, {{1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 6}}, {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 5}}, 
     {{1, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4}}};

cleanUp @ d1
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}
> ```

```
d2 = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2,
      3}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}};

cleanUp @ d2
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}},  
> {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 6}},   
> {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}},   
> {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}}
> ```