# How to generate 3-subsets that satisfy certain conditions without post-filtering?

Tags: combinatorics, subset

**Edits:** In fact it is a set partition problem.

I have a set as follows:

```
s = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}
```

I want to divide the set into 2 groups such that each group has exactly $3$ elements. We want to generate all solutions. Note that  we treat ({"a", "b", "c"}|{"d", "e", "f"}) and ({"d", "e", "f"}|{"a", "b", "c"}) as the same solution.

So first I used the `Subsets` function to generate all 3-subsets and then filtered for duplicate solutions.

```
s3 = Subsets[s, {3}]
DeleteDuplicates[s3, Union[#1] == Union[Complement[s, #2]] &]
```

```
Out[*]: {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b", "d"}, {"a", "b", "e"}, {"a", "b", 
  "f"}, {"a", "c", "d"}, {"a", "c", "e"}, {"a", "c", "f"}, {"a", "d", 
  "e"}, {"a", "d", "f"}, {"a", "e", "f"}}
```

But I feel like the solution is a bit inefficient. In fact, we only need half of all 3-subsets. I wonder if we can only keep one representative  among  same solutions when generating the 3-subsets.

**Edits:** In fact, the problem can be generalized as follows: Given a list of $n$ elements, partition it into $m$ groups, and generate all possible solutions. Similarly,   same solutions are generated only once.

Comment: Note that Union in your code is not needed. "Subsets" does not generate duplicate list elements.

Comment: Thanks. I am worried about the following situation: the oupput of `Complement[{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"a", "b", "c"}] == {"e",  "d", "f"}` is `False`.  But the output of `Complement[{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"a", "b", "c"}] == {"d",  "e", "f"}` is `True`. In fact they should both return `True` in my expectation.

Comment: I believe that in this very specific case you get the set you are looking for by taking half of the subset in order `Subsets` provides them: `Subsets[s, {Length[s]/2}, Binomial[Length[s], Length[s]/2]/2]`.

Comment: You need to sort the list lexicographically as "Subsets" does.

Comment: `First /@ Gather[s3, DisjointQ]` ?

Comment: @Syed It is indeed more concise, but it is still unavoidable to generate all the 3-subsets. I am thinking if there is a way to generate them in some order, by only generating  the representative elements (we know it is  half of all the 3-subsets.) but not all. (As kirma
  observed)

Comment: Could [KSetPartition](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/KSetPartitions/) be of some use?

Comment: @Syed Thank you very much. `KSetPartitions[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, 2]` provides all  2-partitions, which is great and avoids the above repeated scenario; however, it also generates too many; for exmaple, `{{a}, {b, c, d, e, f}}` is  included.   We have requirements for the number of elements in each group. If there could be more flexible options, that would be even better

Comment: What values of $n$ and $m$ are of interest?  And rather than a "feeling" of things being inefficient, consider using `AbsoluteTiming` or `RepeatedTiming` to evaluate the alternatives.

Comment: Related link: [partition-a-set-into-subsets-of-size-k](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/partition-a-set-into-subsets-of-size-k)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to place the first element in each of the subsets formed from `s-1` of the remaining elements, find complements, and recursively subdivvy those complements.

```
subsetSubsets[set_, s_ /; s <= 0] := {}
subsetSubsets[set_, s_] /; s > Length[set] := {set}
subsetSubsets[set_, s_Integer] := Module[
  {first, rest, subsets, firstsets, complements},
  subsets = Subsets[Rest[set], {s - 1}];
  firstsets = Map[Append[#, First[set]] &, subsets];
  complements = Map[Complement[set, #] &, firstsets];
  Flatten[Table[
    Map[Prepend[#, firstsets[[j]]] &, 
     subsetSubsets[complements[[j]], s]]
    , {j, Length[firstsets]}], 1]
  ]
```

Examples:

```
subsetSubsets[Range[6], 3]

(* Out[41]= {{{2, 3, 1}, {5, 6, 4}}, {{2, 4, 1}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{2, 5, 
   1}, {4, 6, 3}}, {{2, 6, 1}, {4, 5, 3}}, {{3, 4, 1}, {5, 6, 
   2}}, {{3, 5, 1}, {4, 6, 2}}, {{3, 6, 1}, {4, 5, 2}}, {{4, 5, 
   1}, {3, 6, 2}}, {{4, 6, 1}, {3, 5, 2}}, {{5, 6, 1}, {3, 4, 2}}} *)

subsetSubsets[Range[6], 2]

(* Out[42]= {{{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {6, 5}}, {{2, 1}, {5, 3}, {6, 4}}, {{2, 
   1}, {6, 3}, {5, 4}}, {{3, 1}, {4, 2}, {6, 5}}, {{3, 1}, {5, 2}, {6,
    4}}, {{3, 1}, {6, 2}, {5, 4}}, {{4, 1}, {3, 2}, {6, 5}}, {{4, 
   1}, {5, 2}, {6, 3}}, {{4, 1}, {6, 2}, {5, 3}}, {{5, 1}, {3, 2}, {6,
    4}}, {{5, 1}, {4, 2}, {6, 3}}, {{5, 1}, {6, 2}, {4, 3}}, {{6, 
   1}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}}, {{6, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 3}}, {{6, 1}, {5, 2}, {4,
    3}}} *)
```